# Return most recent records for each value in a GROUP BY field?

Tags: sql, openoffice-base

I'm a hospital doctor and am trying to produce a report from OO.org Base that will give me the three most recent blood tests for each of my patients.

I have a database that contains the following tables:
"pat" (details of each unique patient)
"visit" (details of each admission, with a one-to-many relationship to "pat")
"bld" (details of each set of blood results, each with a date (bld.date) and time (bld.time) field, with a one-to-many relationship to "visit")

My starting point is the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM "bld"
INNER JOIN "visit" ON "bld"."visit" = "visit"."id"
INNER JOIN "pat" ON "visit"."pat" = "pat"."id";
```

which returns every blood result along with the related patient and admission details.

I'm at the limit of my (fledgling) knowledge with SQL and I'd be very grateful indeed for pointers on how to return only the three most recent results for each admission.

PS It would be a massive bonus if, in addition to the three most recent results I could also have the first result.

Comment: Doc, see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12102216/165673, should be enough to get you started

Answer (score -1):

You didn't tell what sql db you are using but I suppose this will work

```
SELECT TOP 3 *
FROM bld
INNER JOIN visit ON bld.visit = visit.id
INNER JOIN pat ON visit.pat" = pat.id
ORDER BY bld.date desc, bld.time desc
```

> PS It would be a massive bonus if, in addition to the three most
>   recent results I could also have the first result.

Use "SELECT TOP 1 *" instead of "SELECT TOP 3 *".

Comment: Again, this will simply return the three most recent results. I need the three most recent results for each patient.

Answer (score -1):

OK, now that I understand what you are trying to do, try this PHP code:

```
$query1 = "SELECT id FROM pat";

$data1 = mysqli_query($dbc,$query1);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data1)) {
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `bld` 
    INNER JOIN `visit` ON `bld`.`visit` = `visit`.`id`
    INNER JOIN `pat` ON `visit`.`pat` =  {$row['id']}
    OREDER BY `bld`.`date` DESC, `bld`.`time` DESC LIMIT 3";
    $data2 = mysqli_query($dbc,$query2);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data1)) {
        //code to be executed   
    }
}
```

I would recommand you to combine `bld.time` and `bld.date` into one column and use `timestamp` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but this will simply return the three most recent results per se. I want the three most recent results for each patient.