# Get records with max value for each group of grouped SQL results

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

How do you get the rows that contain the max value for each grouped set?

I've seen some overly-complicated variations on this question, and none with a good answer. I've tried to put together the simplest possible example:

Given a table like that below, with person, group, and age columns, how would you get the oldest person in each group? (A tie within a group should give the first alphabetical result)

```
Person | Group | Age
---
Bob  | 1     | 32  
Jill | 1     | 34  
Shawn| 1     | 42  
Jake | 2     | 29  
Paul | 2     | 36  
Laura| 2     | 39
```

Desired result set:

```
Shawn | 1     | 42    
Laura | 2     | 39
```

Comment: _Caution:  The Accepted Answer worked in 2012 when it was written.  However, it no longer works for multiple reasons, as given in the Comments._

Comment: @RickJames - Found a solution on your page here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max#using_variables. 'Using "windowing functions"' for MySQL 8+. Thank you!

Comment: @kJamesy - Yes, but this is the pointer directly to "windowing functions" for that use:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max#using_windowing_functions_

Answer (score 146, accepted):

There's a super-simple way to do this in mysql:

```
select * 
from (select * from mytable order by `Group`, age desc, Person) x
group by `Group`
```

This works because in mysql you're allowed to *not* aggregate non-group-by columns, in which case mysql just returns the *first* row. The solution is to first order the data such that for each group the row you want is first, then group by the columns you want the value for.

You avoid complicated subqueries that try to find the `max()` etc, and also the problems of returning multiple rows when there are more than one with the same maximum value (as the other answers would do)

**Note:** This is a *mysql-only* solution. All other databases I know will throw an SQL syntax error with the message "non aggregated columns are not listed in the group by clause" or similar. Because this solution uses *undocumented* behavior, the more cautious may want to include a test to assert that it *remains* working should a future version of MySQL change this behavior.

#### Version 5.7 update:

Since version 5.7, the [`sql-mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) setting includes [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) by default, so to make this work you must *not* have this option (edit the option file for the server to remove this setting).

Comment: Pretty cool Boh, you get the green- when you say 'allowed to not aggregate non-group by columns', are you saying that that's how MySQL behaves by default? how does that differ from other RDBMS?

Comment: @Yarin Most other RDBMS would not permit you to `GROUP BY Group` in this case since other columns are present in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Should add in `order by Group, age desc,person` as well to accommodate this `A tie within a group should give the first alphabetical result`

Comment: @sel You can if you want, but the important thing is you always get exactly one row per group. Maybe you don't care which row you get, in which case leave it as is.

Comment: @Yarin Ah! Didn't notice that. I've edited the answer to also order by `Person`, which will give you want you want.

Comment: @Bohemian- I've stepped this question up a notch with a [new one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12113699/165673) - would love for you to try and tackle it

Comment: *"mysql just returns the first row."* - maybe this is how it works but it is not guaranteed. The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html) says: **"The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate."**. The server doesn't select rows but values (not necessarily from the same row) for each column or expression that appears in the `SELECT` clause and is not computed using an aggregate function.

Comment: This behaviour changed on [MySQL 5.7.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and by default, it rejects this query because the columns in the `SELECT` clause are not functionally dependent on the `GROUP BY` columns. If it is configured to accept it (` ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled), it works like the previous versions (i.e. the values of those columns are indeterminate).

Comment: Thanx for this.

basically, whenever we select an attribute from a group sql query, it gets the value from the first record, so we need to order it according to our need before we grou by.

Comment: After struggling with this code... which doesn't work at all in MariaDB, I ran across something more useful GROUP_CONCAT. Which allows you to order for the max based on a different column and the concatenate then rest. Very useful if you're trying to get the heaviest Item in an orders table listed first.

Comment: I am surprised this answer got so many upvotes. It is wrong and it is bad. This query is not guaranteed to work. Data in a subquery is an unordered set in spite of the order by clause. MySQL *may* really order the records now and keep that order, but it woudn't break any rule if it stopped doing so in some future version. Then the `GROUP BY` condenses to one record, but all fields will be arbitrarily picked from the records. It *may* be that MySQL currently simply always picks the first row, but it could just as well pick any other row or even values from *different* rows in a future version.

Comment: @thorsten it's not "wrong" because **it works**. And inner queries do retain order. Best practice and [YAGNI](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt) say "do the simplest thing that works *now*". *If* (maybe never) a future version of MySQL behaves unfavourably to this query, you'll find out during the full system regression test, which always happens when planning something like a database upgrade. If it's discovered things have changed, rewrite the query accordingly. Until then, get on with something else that needs doing. Show me a test case that fails.

Comment: Okay, we disagree here. I don't use undocumented features that just happen to work currently and rely on some tests that will hopefully cover this. You know that you are just lucky that the current implementation gets you the complete first record where the docs clearly state that you might got any indeterminate values instead, but you still use it. Some simple session or database setting may change this anytime. I'd consider this too risky.

Comment: @Bohemian Your YAGNI link details what it applies to by saying: "Even if you're totally, totally, totally sure that you'll need a feature later on, don't implement it now." It's talking about features, not about bugs. Saying that a test case is necessary to prove that it could fail is like saying your house is safe because you can't cause it to flood. Not everyone is in a situation where they can easily do a "full system regression" every time some security issue requires something to be upgraded.

Comment: @cesoid YAGNI applies here, because there's no evidence that this behavior will ever change - don't worry about something that will probably never happen. And this *is* a very simple query to test, even as a unit test if your dev env has a mysql instance available (again simple).

Comment: This answer seems wrong. Per the [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), *the server is free to choose any value from each group ... Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Result set sorting occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which value within each group the server chooses.*

Comment: Nevermind, that refers to an ORDER BY on the same level, not a subquery. In any case this does not yield the correct result in MariaDB (which is a shame as it's several magnitudes faster than a self-join).

Comment: In MySQL 8, possibly even before, the optimizer simply gets rid of the subquery entirely. It's also [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html) that an ORDER BY clause of a derived table is simply ignored, if the enclosing query has a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Same thing, MySQL 5.7: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6NwTqvoaTAUjofL34Rz3Ld/3. The ORDER BY is ignored.

Comment: I got wrong data. After group data, the result is now show the max row even I order the data desc.

Comment: It does not work, just gives the first row in the group. I've almost ruined all my data. This answer should be removed.

Comment: @MichaelO. Returning the first row is what it’s *supposed* to do. The inner query in this answer returns all rows in order of group then age descending, so the first row of each group is the oldest person. If your use case isn’t similar to this, don’t use this solution and don’t blame the code (which works) for your decision to use it.

Comment: @Bohemian It returns the first row *without* reverse ordering.

Comment: @MichaelO. Are you ordering the *inner* query? ie `select ... from (select ... order by ...)`?

Comment: @Bohemian I've run it in `db-fiddle` with MySQL version set to 5.6, and it works there, but not in my 5.7 with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` disabled.

Comment: @AndrewKinFatChoi this answer absolutely *is* correct, but you must read the whole answer, especially the last part which states that [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) must *not* be set - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23921117/256196) for how to do that.

Answer (score 433):

The correct solution is:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM `Persons` o                    # 'o' from 'oldest person in group'
  LEFT JOIN `Persons` b             # 'b' from 'bigger age'
      ON o.Group = b.Group AND o.Age < b.Age
WHERE b.Age is NULL                 # bigger age not found
```

#### How it works:

It matches each row from `o` with all the rows from `b` having the same value in column `Group` and a bigger value in column `Age`. Any row from `o` not having the maximum value of its group in column `Age` will match one or more rows from `b`.

The `LEFT JOIN` makes it match the oldest person in group (including the persons that are alone in their group) with a row full of `NULL`s from `b` ('no biggest age in the group').
*Using `INNER JOIN` makes these rows not matching and they are ignored.*

The `WHERE` clause keeps only the rows having `NULL`s in the fields extracted from `b`. They are the oldest persons from each group.

#### Further readings

This solution and many others are explained in the book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/)

Comment: BTW this can return two or more rows for a same group if `o.Age = b.Age`, e.g. if Paul from group 2 is on 39 like Laura. However if we do not want such behavior we can do: `ON o.Group = b.Group AND (o.Age < b.Age or (o.Age = b.Age and o.id < b.id))`

Comment: Incredible! For 20M records it's like 50 times faster than "naive" algorithm (join against a subquery with max())

Comment: Works perfectly with @Todor comments. I would add that if there are further query conditions they must be added in the FROM and in the LEFT JOIN. Something LIKE : ***FROM (SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Age != 32) o LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Age != 32) b*** - if you want to dismiss people who are 32

Comment: @AlainZelink aren't these "further query conditions" be better put in the final WHERE condition list, in order to not introduce subqueries - which were not needed in the original @ axiac answer?

Comment: This solution worked; however, it started getting reported in the slow query log when attempted with 10,000+ rows sharing same ID. Was JOINing on indexed column. A rare case, but figured it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Correct, OK.  Fast, NO.  It is Order(N^2).

Comment: @RickJames With the correct indexes it is correct and fast. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: Please make up your mind. On that page you say it's *"O(2N-3N), depending on `join_buffer_size`"*. With an index on the two columns used on the JOIN condition (Group and Age, in this order) it doesn't have any reason to be O(N^2).

Comment: Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65631090/2742117) for a solution that prevents selecting multiple rows per group and also allows for use of indexes

Comment: I edited the link to my book, because I just published a 2nd edition.

Answer (score 86):

You can join against a subquery that pulls the `MAX(Group)` and `Age`. This method is portable across most RDBMS.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT `Group`, MAX(Age) AS max_age
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY `Group`
) t2
    ON t1.`Group` = t2.`Group` AND t1.Age = t2.max_age;
```

Comment: Michael, thanks for this- but do you have an answer for the issue of returning multiple rows on ties, per Bohemian's comments?

Comment: @Yarin If there were 2 rows for example where `Group = 2, Age = 20`, the subquery would return one of them, but the join `ON` clause would match _both_ of them, so you would get 2 rows back with the same group/age though different vals for the other columns, rather than one.

Comment: So are we saying it's impossible to limit results to one per group unless we go Bohemians MySQL-only route?

Comment: @Yarin no not impossible, just requires more work if there are additional columns - possibly another nested subquery to pull the max associated id for each like pair of group/age, then join against that to get the rest of the row based on id.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (the currently accepted answer will fail on most other RDBMS, and in fact would even fail on many versions of MySQL).

Comment: Good, fast, but risks returning multiple rows.  ("Fast" assumes `INDEX(group, age)` exists.)

Comment: To "pick one of the dups":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max#using_variables

Comment: only if you append ``GROUP BY t1.group`` at the very end, it works

Comment: I retired in 2014 and have forgotten a lot about SQL (and that was Microsoft SQL) so I can't tell why this does not work on my version of mysql.  But after trying several variations, all failing with an unhelpful error message, a much simpler one _without_ a join worked.

Answer (score 34):

In PostgreSQL you can use [DISTINCT ON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("group") * FROM "mytable" ORDER BY "group", "age" DESC;
```

Comment: @Bohemian sorry, I get it know, this is MySQL-only as it includes non-aggregated columns

Comment: @IgorKulagin - Doesn't work in Postgres- Error message: *column "mytable.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function*

Comment: The MySQL query may only work by accident on many occasions. The "SELECT *" may return information that does not correspond to the belonging MAX(age). This answer is wrong. This is probably also the case for SQLite.

Comment: **DISTINCT** rocks! Very helpfull

Comment: I'm looking for MySQL. Your solution seems simple and faster than axiac's solution.

Comment: But this fits the case where we need to select the grouped column and the max column. This does not fits the above requirement where it would results ('Bob', 1, 42) but the expected result is ('Shawn', 1, 42)

Comment: In official documentation there is a note, that this behaviour is valid only for built in MIN and MAX aggregate functions. I've tested this solution. It works for sqlite3, but not for sqlite2. Yes, i know, that sqlite2 is very old version, but it stil exists!

Comment: The question is about MYSQL so this should be the accepted answer imo

Comment: Good for postgres

Comment: This is a wrong answer as mysql "randomly" chooses values from columns that are not GROUP or AGE. This is fine only when you need only these columns.

Comment: How does `ORDER BY "group",` help? What would change if just ordered by `"age" DESC;`

Comment: @porfirion I may be in the minority, but I really *love* how using a single aggregate function in a group brings along the rest of the same row for the ride.  It makes so much sense to me I always wonder why no other DB seems to want to take this approach.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if MySQL has row_number function. If so you can use it to get the desired result. On SQL Server you can do something similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE p
(
 person NVARCHAR(10),
 gp INT,
 age INT
);
GO
INSERT  INTO p
VALUES  ('Bob', 1, 32);
INSERT  INTO p
VALUES  ('Jill', 1, 34);
INSERT  INTO p
VALUES  ('Shawn', 1, 42);
INSERT  INTO p
VALUES  ('Jake', 2, 29);
INSERT  INTO p
VALUES  ('Paul', 2, 36);
INSERT  INTO p
VALUES  ('Laura', 2, 39);
GO

SELECT  t.person, t.gp, t.age
FROM    (
         SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gp ORDER BY age DESC) row
         FROM   p
        ) t
WHERE   t.row = 1;
```

Comment: It does, since 8.0.

Answer (score 7):

Improving on [axiac's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/117259) to avoid selecting multiple rows per group while also allowing for use of indexes

```
SELECT o.*
FROM `Persons` o 
  LEFT JOIN `Persons` b 
      ON o.Group = b.Group AND o.Age < b.Age
  LEFT JOIN `Persons` c 
      ON o.Group = c.Group AND o.Age = c.Age and o.id < c.id
WHERE b.Age is NULL and c.id is null
```

Answer (score 4):

Using ranking method.

```
SELECT @rn :=  CASE WHEN @prev_grp <> groupa THEN 1 ELSE @rn+1 END AS rn,  
   @prev_grp :=groupa,
   person,age,groupa  
FROM   users,(SELECT @rn := 0) r        
HAVING rn=1
ORDER  BY groupa,age DESC,person
```

This sql can be explained as below,

1. select * from users, (select @rn := 0) r
   order by groupa, age desc, person
2. @prev_grp is null
3. @rn :=  CASE WHEN @prev_grp <> groupa THEN 1 ELSE @rn+1 END

   this is a three operator expression
   like this, rn = 1 if prev_grp != groupa else rn=rn+1
4. having rn=1 filter out the row you need

Comment: sel - need some explanation - I've never even seen `:=` before - what is that?

Comment: := is assignment operator. You could read more on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: I'll have to dig into this- I think the answer overcomplicates our scenario, but thanks for teaching me something new..

Answer (score 3):

I would not use Group as column name since it is reserved word. However following SQL would work.

```
SELECT a.Person, a.Group, a.Age FROM [TABLE_NAME] a
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT `Group`, MAX(Age) AS oldest FROM [TABLE_NAME] 
  GROUP BY `Group`
) b ON a.Group = b.Group AND a.Age = b.oldest
```

Comment: Thanks, though this returns multiple records for an age when there is a tie

Comment: @Yarin how would decide which is the correct oldest person? Multiple answers seem to be the rightest answer otherwise use limit and order

Answer (score 3):

My solution works only if you need retrieve only one column, however for my needs was the best solution found in terms of performance (it use only one single query!):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(column_x ORDER BY column_y),',',1) AS xyz,
   column_z
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column_z;
```

It use GROUP_CONCAT in order to create an ordered concat list and then I substring to only the first one.

Comment: Can confirm that you can get multiple columns by sorting on the same key inside the group_concat, but need to write a separate group_concat/index/substring for each column.

Comment: Bonus here is that you can add multiple columns to the sort inside the group_concat and it would resolve the ties easily and guarantee only one record per group. Well done on the simple and efficient solution!

Answer (score 2):

axiac's solution is what worked best for me in the end. I had an additional complexity however: a calculated "max value", derived from two columns.

Let's use the same example: I would like the oldest person in each group. If there are people that are equally old, take the tallest person.

I had to perform the left join two times to get this behavior:

```
SELECT o1.* WHERE
    (SELECT o.*
    FROM `Persons` o
    LEFT JOIN `Persons` b
    ON o.Group = b.Group AND o.Age < b.Age
    WHERE b.Age is NULL) o1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT o.*
    FROM `Persons` o
    LEFT JOIN `Persons` b
    ON o.Group = b.Group AND o.Age < b.Age
    WHERE b.Age is NULL) o2
ON o1.Group = o2.Group AND o1.Height < o2.Height 
WHERE o2.Height is NULL;
```

Hope this helps! I guess there should be better way to do this though...

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle below query can give the desired result.

```
SELECT group,person,Age,
  ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group ORDER BY age desc ,person asc) as rankForEachGroup
  FROM tablename where rankForEachGroup=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CTEs - Common Table Expressions:

```
WITH MyCTE(MaxPKID, SomeColumn1)
AS(
SELECT MAX(a.MyTablePKID) AS MaxPKID, a.SomeColumn1
FROM MyTable1 a
GROUP BY a.SomeColumn1
  )
SELECT b.MyTablePKID, b.SomeColumn1, b.SomeColumn2 MAX(b.NumEstado)
FROM MyTable1 b
INNER JOIN MyCTE c ON c.MaxPKID = b.MyTablePKID
GROUP BY b.MyTablePKID, b.SomeColumn1, b.SomeColumn2

--Note: MyTablePKID is the PrimaryKey of MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with CTE as 
(select Person, 
[Group], Age, RN= Row_Number() 
over(partition by [Group] 
order by Age desc) 
from yourtable)`


`select Person, Age from CTE where RN = 1`
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'm getting the N max rows per group in mysql

```
SELECT co.id, co.person, co.country
FROM person co
WHERE (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM person ci
WHERE  co.country = ci.country AND co.id < ci.id
) < 1
;
```

how it works:

- self join to the table
- groups are done by `co.country = ci.country`
- N elements per group are controlled by `) < 1` so for 3 elements - ) < 3
- to get max or min depends on: `co.id < ci.id`

  - co.id < ci.id - max
  - co.id > ci.id - min

Full example here:

[mysql select n max values per group](http://blog.softhints.com/mysql-select-n-max-values-per-group/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE age IN (SELECT MAX(age) FROM mytable GROUP BY `Group`) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, though this returns multiple records for an age when there is a tie

Comment: Also, this query would be incorrect in the case that there is a 39-year-old in group 1.  In that case, that person would also be selected, even though the max age in group 1 is higher.

Answer (score 0):

This method has the benefit of allowing you to rank by a different column, and not trashing the other data. It's quite useful in a situation where you are trying to list orders with a column for items, listing the heaviest first.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
SELECT person, group,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT age
        ORDER BY age DESC SEPARATOR ', follow up: '
    )
FROM sql_table
GROUP BY group;
```

Answer (score 0):

let the table name be people

```
select O.*              -- > O for oldest table
from people O , people T
where O.grp = T.grp and 
O.Age = 
(select max(T.age) from people T where O.grp = T.grp
  group by T.grp)
group by O.grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

If ID(and all coulmns) is needed from mytable

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mytable
WHERE
    id NOT IN (
        SELECT
            A.id
        FROM
            mytable AS A
        JOIN mytable AS B ON A. GROUP = B. GROUP
        AND A.age < B.age
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.*
FROM `Persons` o                   
  LEFT JOIN `Persons` b            
      ON o.Group = b.Group AND o.Age < b.Age
WHERE b.Age is NULL  
group by o.Group
```

Comment: Please explain what your answer is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I retired in 2014 and my memory of Microsoft SQL is a bit rusty.  I found this question in looking for a solution to a challenge in mysql.  The answer that was said to be portable, when I changed to my table & column names got mysql to complain it wasn't valid with no further explanation.  Several variations got the same unhelpful complaint.  Finally, I decided to try my own much simpler instinct, and it worked.  To get the most recent change for each xref from a list of changes, I use

```
SELECT xref, MAX(change_time) AS last_change 
FROM ug_change 
GROUP BY xref;
```