# How can I get the highest rating album for each artist?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Album
Title                                     Artist                Year Type        Rating
My World                                  Justin Bieber         2009 STUDIO           4
My Worlds: The Collection                 Justin Bieber         2010 COMPILATION      4
21                                        Adele                 2011 STUDIO           5
Adele Live at the Royal Albert Hall       Adele                 2011 LIVE             4
Get to Heaven                             Everything Everything 2015 STUDIO           5
One of the boys                           Katy Perry            2008 STUDIO           3
Overexposed                               Maroon 5              2012 STUDIO           5
Live From Le Cabaret: In Montreal. Quebec Maroon 5              2008 LIVE             4
Pure Heroine                              Lorde                 2013 STUDIO           4
```

So above is the Album, how can I get each artist's own highest rating album?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a good practice to inline the image in your question instead of providing a link that opens in another tab. This makes your question easier to read and understand.

Comment: It's better practice to dispense with a linked image altogether

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option joining to a subquery using the `max` aggregate:

```
select a.title, a.artist
from album a join (
    select artist, max(rating) maxrating
    from almum
    group by artist) t on a.artist = t.artist and a.rating = t.maxrating
```

This can return multiple titles per artist if they share the highest rating.

---

And perhaps even easier with an `outer join`:

```
select a.*
from album a                   
  left join album a2            
      on a.artist = a2.artist and a.rating < a2.rating
where a2.rating is null
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3db6a/1)

Comment: I like the second answer. It's confusing at first but very elegant... and no subqueries needed!

Comment: @soulfreshner The first solution is orders of magnitude faster than the second.

Comment: @Strawberry -- I thought they were pretty comparable in `mysql`.  I generally use the first option (really because of readability) -- does it perform better as well?

Comment: @sgeddes No. Not remotely comparable. I mean, your first solution is likely to be as good as or better than any other method.

Comment: I'm old school, so I like the second method too (I've even seen it called the 'Strawberry' method from time to time - but while it's nice to have something named after me, I'd prefer it to be the sgeddes method ;-) )

Comment: @Strawberry Maybe, I'm not sure. On the one hand, the latter removes an aggregate subquery but on the other it joins multiple times on the 'rating' field. I would think that for small numbers of items per artist, the second would be faster, but I would love to see some actual benchmarks. Either way, the second solution just seems smart and out of the box, which is why I like it :)

Comment: "Maybe, I'm not sure" @soulfreshner It's OK. I am. Sparsity of results has negligible impact on the relative performance of these queries,

Comment: @Strawberry we live we learn :). Could you supply a link to more info on this? I'm genuinely interested.

Comment: Check out EXPLAINEXTENDED's blog posts on the subjects. While the tests might be slightly out-of-date, I doubt the relative performance will have moved much. I think Roland Bouman and/or Guiseppe Maxia may have explored something similar once upon a time too. But you could knock up a test yourself in 10 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT* 
FROM(SELECT* FROM`Album` ORDER BY `Artist`, `Rating` DESC) x
GROUP BY `Artist`
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results) for more info, it's quite similar. Basically, sort it so that you have the table rearranged by artist, with the highest rating at the top for each, then group it to pull out the first record for each.

Comment: I never liked this as a solution -- just didn't feel right imo... I thought it actually could return arbitrary values, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: The return values for this is not guaranteed... you are grouping by artist, there is no guarantee that you will get the first record. Though this does seem to be the case with mysql.