# How can I get the latest package for all packages in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `packages` (with id, name as attributes) and `releases` (with url, upload_time, downloaded_bytes as attributes). Every package can have arbitrary many releases. I want a list of all packages with their latest release.

Currently, I have the following working code:

```
sql = ("SELECT `packages`.`id`, `name` FROM `packages`")
cursor.execute(sql)
packages = cursor.fetchall()
for pkg in packages:
    sql = ("SELECT `url` FROM `releases` "
           "WHERE `package_id` = %s "
           "AND `downloaded_bytes` = 0 "
           "ORDER BY `upload_time` DESC LIMIT 1")
    cursor.execute(sql, (pkg['id'], ))
    url = cursor.fetchone()
    if url is not None:
        package_url = url['url']
        package_analysis.main(pkg['name'], package_url)
        logging.info("Package '%s' done.", pkg['name'])
```

However, I think this is an ugly solution as I execute a lot of queries where I should only execute one query.

Can I do this in one query? How would the query look like?

Please note: I only want one result for each package. That means, the package `numpy` should only give the result for `url="https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp35/n/numpy/numpy-1.10.1-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl"` (version 1.10.1) and *not* 99 results.

### What I've tried

```
SELECT
    `packages`.`id`,
    `packages`.`name`,
    `releases`.`url`,
    `releases`.`upload_time`,
    `releases`.`release_number`
FROM
    `packages`
JOIN
    `releases` ON `releases`.`package_id` = `packages`.`id`
GROUP BY
    `packages`.`name`
ORDER BY
    `releases`.`upload_time` DESC
```

But that gives a seemingly random value for `upload_time` (and also `url`).

Comment: You might want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results
That's the general form of the problem. The (in my opinion) best answer is using left joins.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
select p.id, p.name, r.url, r.upload_time, r.release_number from
(select p.id, max(r.release_number) release_number from packages p
join releases r on p.id = r.package_id
group by p.id) a
join packages p on p.id = a.id
join releases r on r.release_number = a.release_number
```

It assumes that release_number is sortable, if not possible you can use max upload time instead.

Comment: You might want to sort by `upload_time` to satisfy the question.

Comment: For testing purposes I've added `WHERE p.name="numpy"`. This gave 91 results. It should only give 1.

Comment: Especially bad: `r.url` seems not to belong (always) to `p.name`.

Comment: True. Grouping by `p.id` in the inner query is not meaningful.

Comment: To get maximum release_number by package, you need to group by p.id, so the grouping in the inner query has a meaning. From the query  @moose tried, url belongs to the release table.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/562769) (thank you [Emiswelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130060/emiswelt)) for mentioning it:

```
SELECT
    `packages`.`id`,
    `packages`.`name`,
    `o`.`url`,
    `o`.`upload_time`,
    `o`.`release_number`
FROM
    `releases` o
LEFT JOIN
    `releases` b  ON `o`.`package_id` = `b`.`package_id`
    AND `o`.`upload_time` < `b`.`upload_time`
JOIN
    `packages` ON `packages`.`id` = o.package_id
WHERE
    `b`.`upload_time` is NULL
    AND `o`.`downloaded_bytes` = 0
ORDER BY
    `packages`.`name`
LIMIT 10
```

The query finishes execution within a fraction of a second.