# Selecting Multipal Row in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have these table in my database:

```
id  Name    Order Date
1   A       29-Dec
2   B       15-Dec
3   C       12-Oct
4   A       15-Dec
5   B       15-Sep
6   A       15-Sep
7   B       15-Aug
8   C       15-Aug
9   A       15-Jul
```

Expected Output:-

```
Name    QTY     Last Order Date
A       4       29-Dec
B       3       15-Dec
C       2       12-Oct
```

How to do this, Please help.

Also I have to select only those record whose last order date is greater than 10 days.

The purpose behind this query is to send such customer a notification who are not ordering since 10 days. How to do this, Please help...

Comment: Can any o one help please...

Comment: Store dates using a date data type. Then get back to us.

Comment: The date format is = 2015-06-25 16:42:29

Comment: Good.Please edit your question accordingly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get records with max value for each group of grouped SQL results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this... the field and table names are different, please change it accordingly

```
select name, count(name), date from abc group by name order by date desc
```

Comment: Yes It worked, I got it very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```sql
SELECT name, count(name), MAX(date) as latest_order_date
FROM Orders 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY name ASC
```

For your comment about how to select only those record where last order date is greater than 10 days, you can use [HAVING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) and [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

```sql
SELECT name, count(name), MAX(date) as latest_order_date
FROM Orders 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING DATEDIFF(NOW(),latest_order_date) > 10
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Comment: I was about to answer the same thing. Here is a [working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cfd2e/4).

Comment: Hi Sir, it worked.... Great Job, Thank you Cedric Miachon, Stay  Blessed

Comment: From the above table I want to select only those record where last order date is greater than 10 days.

For Example if any customer did not placed any order since last 10 day, send them notification. How to do this. please help....

Comment: like that : SELECT name, count(name), MAX(date) as latest_order_date
FROM Orders 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING DATEDIFF(NOW(),latest_order_date) > 10
ORDER BY name ASC

Comment: @SaleemJafar  I update the answer below

Comment: Your are absolutely wright. It worked perfectly. Thank YOu