# How does GROUP BY DESC select its order?

Tags: mysql

So I am creating sections for a store. The store can have multiple scopes, if there isn't a `section_identifier` set for a given `store_id` it should fallback to the global store which is `0`.

The SQL command that I want should return a list of `section_options` for any related given store.

Example of my table:

`SELECT * FROM my_table:`

```
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
| id | section_identifier | option_identifier    | store_id |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
| 17 | header             | header_option_one    |        1 |
| 18 | footer             | footer_option_one    |        0 |
| 19 | homepage_feature   | homepage_feature_one |        0 |
| 23 | header             | header_option_three  |        0 |
| 25 | homepage_feature   | homepage_feature_one |        1 |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
```

So `section_identifier` is unique, the IDs I need back for store 1 would be 17, 18 and 25.

When I run:

`SELECT * FROM my_table GROUP BY section_identifier` it returns:

```
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
| id | section_identifier | option_identifier    | store_id |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
| 18 | footer             | footer_option_one    |        0 |
| 23 | header             | header_option_three  |        0 |
| 19 | homepage_feature   | homepage_feature_one |        0 |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
```

This means if I run `SELECT * FROM my_table GROUP BY section_identifier DESC`:

I get the response (this is my desired output):

```
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
| id | section_identifier | option_identifier    | store_id |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
| 25 | homepage_feature   | homepage_feature_one |        1 |
| 17 | header             | header_option_one    |        1 |
| 18 | footer             | footer_option_one    |        0 |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
```

Although this works, I have no understanding of as to why.

Its my understanding the initial `GROUP BY` should get the first instance in the database, IE the response I expect should be:

```
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
| id | section_identifier | option_identifier    | store_id |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
| 18 | footer             | footer_option_one    |        0 |
| 17 | header             | header_option_three  |        1 |
| 19 | homepage_feature   | homepage_feature_one |        0 |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
```

However, it seems to be referencing my `store_id` somehow? I have tried a few different combinations and Im weirdly getting my expected result each time but I have no understanding as to why.

Can anybody explain this to me please?

PS

I have tried updating the `option_identifier` of `id = 7` to see if MySql references the latest saved on disk and it didn't change the result.

**Also**: I'm not planning on using this feature or asking for an alternative, I'm asking what's going on with it?

Comment: Something is pretty weird here... Are these the actual tables, data and queries? You also mention that the `section_identifier` is unique, I suppose you mean unique per `store_id`?

Comment: Yes the indexes of the table are `store_id` and `section_id`. IE these two values must be unique.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table GROUP BY section_identifier
```

is an invalid `SQL` query.

#### How `GROUP BY` works?

Let's get the query above and see how `GROUP BY` works. First the database engine selects all the rows that match the `WHERE` clause. There is no `WHERE` clause in this query; this means all the rows of the table are used to generate the result set.

It then groups the rows using the expressions specified in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
| id | section_identifier | option_identifier    | store_id |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
| 17 | header             | header_option_one    |        1 |
| 23 | header             | header_option_three  |        0 |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
| 18 | footer             | footer_option_one    |        0 |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
| 19 | homepage_feature   | homepage_feature_one |        0 |
| 25 | homepage_feature   | homepage_feature_one |        1 |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------+
```

I marked the groups in the listing above to make everything clear.

On the next step, from each group the database engine produces **a single row**. But how?

The `SELECT` clause of your query is `SELECT *`. `*` stands for the full list of table columns; in this case, `SELECT *` is a short way to write:

```
SELECT id, section_identifier, option_identifier, store_id
```

Let's analyze the values of column `id` for the first group. What value should the database engine choose for `id`? `17` or `23`? Why `17` and why `23`?

It does not have any criteria to favor `17` over `23`. It just picks one of them (probably `17` but this depends on a lot of internal factors) and goes one.

There is no problem to determine the value for `section_identifier`. It is the column used to `GROUP BY`, all its values in a group are equal.

The choosing dilemma occurs again on columns `option_identifier` and `store_id`.

---

According to the standard `SQL` your query is not valid and it cannot be executed. However, some database engines run it as described above. The values for expressions that are not (at least one of the below):

- used in the `GROUP BY` clause;
- used with [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) in the `SELECT` clause;
- functionally dependent of columns used in the `GROUP BY` clause;

are indeterminate.

Since version `5.7.5`, `MySQL` implements [functional dependency detection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and, by default, it rejects an invalid `GROUP BY` query like yours.

#### How to make it work

It's not clear for me how you want to get the result set. Anyway, if you want to get some rows from the table then `GROUP BY` **is not** the correct way to do it. `GROUP BY` **does not** select rows from a table, it generates new values using the values from the table. A row generated by `GROUP BY`, most of the times, do not match any row from the source table.

You can find a possible solution to your problem in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/4265352). You'll have to write the query yourself after you read and understand the idea (and is very clear to you how the "winner" rows should be selected).

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY sorts records in ascending order by default. Your store_id is not being referenced at all instead the records returned are sorted in ascending order of the section_identifier