# MYSQL GROUPBY returning incorrect value

Tags: mysql

I've experiencing a problem related to using the GROUPBY in my query. When I group by both p.ID and cc.CarClassHash, I'm being returned duplicate rows. However, when I only group by p.ID, the query works as I intend it to with only one p.ID and cc.CarClassHash. However, the problem is the cc.carClassHash value being returned with the p.ID is random. Bottom line is if I group by two values, I'll get all data returned with multiple p.ID's. If I group by one, I'll get one p.ID, but still with the wrong car.

Is there a way I could make sure the cc.carClassHash value corresponds to the correct minimum e.alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds value?

I've attached a screenshot of the problem with sample data. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw8mV.jpg
The first two rows are grouped by only the p.ID (One p.ID as intended, but random car value). The bottom four rows are grouped by p.ID and cc.ownedCarId (with the correct cars, but now multiple data p.ID's.**My desired result is having the minimum time per each p.ID with the cc.ownedCarId without any other results per the same player.**

This is the code I'm using which returns duplicate data when grouping by the two values.

```
SELECT p.ID, e.personaId, e.ID AS event_id, e.EVENTID, e.carId, 
         MIN(e.alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds) AS alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds,
           p.iconIndex,
           p.name AS p_name, cc.name AS c_name, cc.carClassHash AS c_hash, ev.carClassHash, ccs.full_name AS cs_name, b.user_id AS banned_status, ev.legitTime, e.bustedCount, e.distanceToFinish, e.finishReason, e.fractionCompleted
           FROM EVENT_DATA e
    INNER JOIN PERSONA p ON e.personaId = p.ID
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMCAR cc ON cc.ownedCarId = e.carId 
    INNER JOIN CAR_CLASSES ccs ON ccs.store_name = cc.name
    INNER JOIN USER u ON u.ID = p.USERID
    LEFT JOIN BAN b ON b.user_id = u.ID
    INNER JOIN EVENTSAVED ev ON ev.ID = e.EVENTID


    WHERE (e.EVENTID = '28' AND e.alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds > '0' AND e.bustedCount < '1' AND e.distanceToFinish = '0' AND e.fractionCompleted > '0.9' AND cc.carClassHash = ev.carClassHash AND e.alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds > ev.legitTime AND e.finishReason != '2' OR e.finishReason = '1')

GROUP BY p.ID, cc.ownedCarId

ORDER BY alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds ASC



      CREATE TABLE `EVENT` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `baseCashReward` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `baseRepReward` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `eventModeId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `finalCashRewardMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `finalRepRewardMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `isEnabled` bit(1) NOT NULL,
 `isLocked` bit(1) NOT NULL,
 `legitTime` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `levelCashRewardMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `levelRepRewardMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `maxCarClassRating` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `maxLevel` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `maxPlayers` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `minCarClassRating` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `minLevel` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `minTopSpeedTrigger` float NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `perfectStartCashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `perfectStartRepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank1CashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank1RepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank2CashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank2RepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank3CashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank3RepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank4CashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank4RepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank5CashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank5RepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank6CashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank6RepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank7CashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank7RepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank8CashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank8RepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `topSpeedCashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `topSpeedRepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `carClassHash` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=536 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `EVENT_DATA` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `bestLapDurationInMilliseconds` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `bustedCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `carId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `copsDeployed` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `copsDisabled` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `copsRammed` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `costToState` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `distanceToFinish` float NOT NULL,
  `eventDurationInMilliseconds` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `eventModeId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eventSessionId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finishReason` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fractionCompleted` float NOT NULL,
  `hacksDetected` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `heat` float NOT NULL,
  `infractions` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `longestJumpDurationInMilliseconds` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `numberOfCollisions` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `perfectStart` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `personaId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rank` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `roadBlocksDodged` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `spikeStripsDodged` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sumOfJumpsDurationInMilliseconds` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `topSpeed` float NOT NULL,
  `EVENTID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_EVENTDATA_EVENT` (`EVENTID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_EVENTDATA_EVENT` FOREIGN KEY (`EVENTID`) REFERENCES `EVENT` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=157134 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  

CREATE TABLE `PERSONA` (
 `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `boost` double NOT NULL,
 `cash` double NOT NULL,
 `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `curCarIndex` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `iconIndex` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `motto` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `percentToLevel` float NOT NULL,
 `rating` double NOT NULL,
 `rep` double NOT NULL,
 `repAtCurrentLevel` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `USERID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `badges` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 KEY `FK_PERSONA_USER` (`USERID`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_PERSONA_USER` FOREIGN KEY (`USERID`) REFERENCES `USER` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4043 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `CUSTOMCAR` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `baseCar` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `carClassHash` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `isPreset` bit(1) NOT NULL,
 `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `physicsProfileHash` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `resalePrice` float NOT NULL,
 `rideHeightDrop` float NOT NULL,
 `skillModSlotCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `ownedCarId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `FK_CUSTOMCAR_OWNEDCAR` (`ownedCarId`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMCAR_OWNEDCAR` FOREIGN KEY (`ownedCarId`) REFERENCES `OWNEDCAR` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16087 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `CAR_CLASSES` (
 `store_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `ac_stock` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ac_var1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ac_var2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ac_var3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `full_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `ha_stock` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ha_var1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ha_var2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ha_var3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `hash` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `manufactor` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `model` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `product_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `ts_stock` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ts_var1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ts_var2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ts_var3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`store_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `USER` (
 `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `EMAIL` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `HWID` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `IP_ADDRESS` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `isAdmin` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lastLogin` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `PASSWORD` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `premium` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `gameHardwareHash` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `authservUUID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3887 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `BAN` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `data` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `endsAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `reason` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `type` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `FK_BAN_USER` (`user_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_BAN_USER` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `USER` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `EVENTSAVED` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `baseCashReward` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `baseRepReward` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `eventModeId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `finalCashRewardMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `finalRepRewardMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `isEnabled` bit(1) NOT NULL,
 `isLocked` bit(1) NOT NULL,
 `legitTime` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `levelCashRewardMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `levelRepRewardMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `maxCarClassRating` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `maxLevel` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `maxPlayers` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `minCarClassRating` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `minLevel` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `minTopSpeedTrigger` float NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `perfectStartCashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `perfectStartRepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank1CashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank1RepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank2CashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank2RepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank3CashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank3RepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank4CashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank4RepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank5CashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank5RepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank6CashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank6RepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank7CashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank7RepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank8CashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `rank8RepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `topSpeedCashMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `topSpeedRepMultiplier` float NOT NULL,
 `carClassHash` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=536 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `OWNEDCAR` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `durability` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `expirationDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `heat` float NOT NULL,
 `ownershipType` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `carSlotId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `FK_OWNEDCAR_CARSLOT` (`carSlotId`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_OWNEDCAR_CARSLOT` FOREIGN KEY (`carSlotId`) REFERENCES `CARSLOT` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16088 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `CARSLOT` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `PersonaId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `FK_CARSLOT_PERSONA` (`PersonaId`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_CARSLOT_PERSONA` FOREIGN KEY (`PersonaId`) REFERENCES `PERSONA` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16088 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Your question is too broad, and unclear. Please convert the problem using  **minimal** sample data showcasing your requirements. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Huh.. you look like you're parsing assetto corsa data.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong.. but your GROUP BY statement could legitimately be replaced with    GROUP BY e.personaId, e.carId   correct?

Comment: @DarbyM Yes, but that would return multiple times for each person. I'm still looking to get the minimum time for each person but also get the corresponding row data (in this case, the correct car versus the first one in database.)

Comment: Understood...  working my way through it, to make sure I understand.   (not so easy without the DB in front of ya)

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate it. I've been stumped for the past few hours trying to figure it out. I think it's still critical to Group by that p.ID, but the trick is getting the corresponding cc.ownedCarID value since it pulls the first car value regardless of whether or not it's the minimum time.

Comment: Think there might be a problem in your Where statement.   You are selecting certain rows from EVENT_DATA base on a long chain of AND conditions (which is fine) but then ended with a single OR condition that would override all the AND conditions if it was true but they aren't.  Is this intended?

Comment: for the record, you are *not* receiving duplicate rows;  `GROUP BY` **instructs** the RDBMS to return a row for each unique set of combined `GROUP BY` columns; if there are multiple values of cc.CarClassHash for a given p.ID, then that's what you're going to get: one row for each such combination

Comment: I see...so would it still be possible to group by p.ID and also get the corresponding car value then instead of the first value the database pulls with it?

Comment: Yeah, I know I'm already ordering by minimum time ASC, but how would I order by the cc.carClassHash corresponding to it since it isn't a numerical value? It's not like I could say, "ORDER BY the Minimum value of cc.carClassHash".

Comment: can you set up a SQL Fiddle with your table schema and sample data?  thx

Comment: This doesn't do what you're after does it?   GROUP BY e.personaId, e.carId

HAVING e.alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds = MIN(e.alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds)

ORDER BY e.alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds ASC

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35748555/4265352). It explains how a `GROUP BY` query is executed and why your (invalid SQL) query returns random values.

Comment: @landru27 I'm working on that currently. - Darby, That returns the correct car with the time, but it also shows all times per person.

Comment: @ccc  I'm sorry, but I'm not going to work from an image, when there are fine alternatives available, such as you posting the (MCVE) details as an edit to your question, or you putting them into a SQL Fiddle

Comment: deleted two of my comments in favor of what @DarbyM and @ axiac have added

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this will give you what you want, but with one caveat:

```
SELECT p.ID, e.personaId, e.ID AS event_id, e.EVENTID, e.carId, e.alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds,
p.iconIndex, p.name AS p_name, cc.name AS c_name, cc.carClassHash AS c_hash, ev.carClassHash, ccs.full_name AS cs_name, b.user_id AS banned_status, 
ev.legitTime, e.bustedCount, e.distanceToFinish, e.finishReason, e.fractionCompleted

FROM EVENT_DATA e

INNER JOIN (SELECT personaId, MIN(alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds) AS alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds
        FROM EVENT_DATA
        GROUP BY personaId) f
    ON f.personaId = e.personaId AND f.alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds = e.alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds

INNER JOIN PERSONA p 
    ON p.ID = e.personaId 
INNER JOIN CUSTOMCAR cc 
    ON cc.ownedCarId = e.carId 
INNER JOIN EVENTSAVED ev 
    ON ev.ID = e.EVENTID
INNER JOIN CAR_CLASSES ccs 
    ON ccs.store_name = cc.name
INNER JOIN USER u 
    ON u.ID = p.USERID   
LEFT JOIN BAN b 
    ON b.user_id = u.ID

WHERE e.finishReason = '1'
OR (e.EVENTID = '28' 
    AND e.alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds > '0' 
    AND e.bustedCount < '1' 
    AND e.distanceToFinish = '0' 
    AND e.fractionCompleted > '0.9' 
    AND cc.carClassHash = ev.carClassHash 
    AND e.alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds > ev.legitTime 
    AND e.finishReason != '2')

ORDER BY e.alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds ASC
```

**Caveat**

The one caveat is, IF the same user, gets the EXACT same time, with a different car.  that user will in fact have 2 "Best Times" with 2 different cars.

Let me know if this works out for ya.