# mysql most popular page in 5 minute intervals

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table "page" that contains fields "page_name" and "page_timestamp". The table stores page and times requests that were made on a website.  I'm trying to write a query that gives me the most hit page for every 5 min period.

Output like

```
Time    Page           Hits 
12:00  index.html     34
12:05  page1.html     11
12:10  index.html     44
```

This is one attempt, but no output.

```
select pages_timestamp,
    (select  count( pages_name)
     from pages t2
     where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.pages_timestamp) DIV 300 =
         UNIX_TIMESTAMP(pages_timestamp)
     group by pages_name
     order by count(pages_name) desc
     limit 1 )  
from pages
where ...
group by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(pages_timestamp ) DIV 300
```

I'm sure there is a better approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes `page_timestamp` is a `DATETIME` type.

[Here is a sample](http://rextester.com/YCU82917) with some data I created, it helps to visualize the output.

So first off, lets create a function for time rounding, this will declutter our query:

```
drop function if exists rtime;
create function rtime (time DATETIME)
returns DATETIME

BEGIN
DECLARE newtime DATETIME;
set newtime = from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(time)/300)*300);
return newtime;
END;
```

Next let's explore our data a little bit.  I want to pull all `Time`, `Page`, and `Count(Page_Name)`, grouping by interval and page.

```
SELECT
Time, Page, Hits 
from (
    select rtime(pages_timestamp) as time
    , page_name as page
    ,  count(page_name) as hits 
    from pages 
    group by page_name, rtime(pages_timestamp) 
    order by rtime(pages_timestamp), hits desc) g ;
```

This orders our aggregated table by time interval then the number of hits.  Since our groups are ordered by most hits desc we can pull the first row.  In MySQL *we can non-aggregate non-group by columns* ([src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results).  This gives us the first row per group, the one with the most hits.  We just `SELECT *` from the above table grouping only by time:

```
select * from 
(select time, page, hits 
from (
     select rtime(pages_timestamp) as time
     , page_name as page
     ,  count(page_name) as hits 
     from pages 
     group by page_name, rtime(pages_timestamp) 
     order by rtime(pages_timestamp), hits desc
     ) g 
) h group by time;
```

Disclaimer!: If there is a tie, if two pages both have the most hits, this will only pull one record.

Comment: Would it be better to have a function for floor 5 min TIMESTAMP and use that for shorthand?  Suggestions welcome

Comment: `select 
SEC_TO_TIME( (ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(user_log_pages_timestamp)/300)) * 300)
, 
(
select count(user_log_pages_basename) 
from user_log_pages p
where  
SEC_TO_TIME( (ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(user_log_pages_timestamp)/300)) * 300)   =              < this part not working 
SEC_TO_TIME( (ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(p.user_log_pages_timestamp)/300)) * 300)
group by p.user_log_pages_basename order by count(user_log_pages_basename) desc limit 1 
) 
From user_log_pages  
GROUP BY
SEC_TO_TIME( (ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(user_log_pages_timestamp)/300)) * 300) 

Out
07:55:00 66
08:00:00 66`

Comment: working on this.  Quick question, what type is your pages_timestamp?  Is it datetime?  Or is it stored as string like 12:01 etc?

Comment: Your example works perfectly. Thank you so much. yes its a datetime field.