# MySql sort on join?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `jobs, notes`.

I want to output a list of jobs that are of `status='lost'` along with the **most recent** note for that job (based on the date the note was created).

Here's my query:

```
select jobs.id, jobs.name, jobs.status
inner join notes on jobs.id=notes.jobId
where jobs.status='lost'
group by jobs.id
order by notes.createDate DESC
```

I would have thought that the output would show the most recent note for a given job. But it shows the first note for that job.  I have changed sort from DESC to ASC just to see what happens...and the output is the same.

Then I tried to nest a select from notes inside the main select..and it hung.

This should be easy and I am sure it is..what am I missing ?

Comment: Actually, it returns arbitrary (indeterminate) results. You're missing the manual, which has a whole chapter on this topic.

Comment: The manual page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: ... and an answer to a similar question that can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/4265352

Answer (score 0):

There is many options to solve this, but you may use a sub query.

```
select jobs.id, jobs.name, jobs.status
(select noteField from notes on jobs.id=notes.jobId order by createDate desc limit 1) note
where jobs.status='lost'
```

Answer (score 0):

When I'm in a similar boat, I've resorted to using a subquery on the join:

```
select jobs.id, jobs.name, jobs.status
from jobs
inner join notes on jobs.id = notes.jobId
   and notes.createDate = (select max(notes.createDate)
                          from notes
                          where jobs.id = notes.createDate
                          group by notes.jobId)
where jobs.status='lost'
group by jobs.id
order by notes.createDate DESC
```