# get latest(date) row of groups

Tags: mysql, sql

my problem is, that I stuck with this I guess simple problem. 
Now 2 evenings Grrr...
I created a small example to keep it simple:

The source table looks like that: Some obj with some random status.
These statuses can be changed/updated by insert a new row.

```
Id | obj| status | date
---+----+--------+-----
1  | 1  | green  | 2013
2  | 1  | green  | 2014
3  | 1  | yellow | 2015
4  | 1  | orange | 2016 <- Last status of 1
5  | 2  | green  | 2013
6  | 2  | green  | 2014 <- Last status of 2
7  | 3  | green  | 2010
8  | 3  | red    | 2012 <- Last status of 3
```

I would need to get an output like that:

```
obj| status | date
---+--------+-----
1  | orange | 2016
2  | green  | 2014
3  | red    | 2012
```

text: The output shows the latest status of ech obj.

I hope somebody can help me..

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12102200/1324815.  Please note, I would strongly recommend using the [left outer join answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/1324815) instead of the selected answer on that post.  With correct indexing, it almost always more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple correlated subquery in the `where` clause does the trick:

```
select obj, status, date
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.status = t.status);
```

Comment: thank you :)
I did't tought that it would be that easy - lesson learned :)

Answer (score 0):

select obj, status, date
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.Obj= t.Obj);