# Wrong ID is retrieve during a select query with 6 joined tables

Tags: php, mysql

This are my tables:

**cb_paymentscheduledetail**

```
id | name                  | date_entered          | deleted | due_date   | amount | status
1  | #1 Payment For Inv# 1 | 2016-07-15 06:11:55   | 0       | 2016-07-08 | 147.25 | Unpaid
2  | #2 Payment For Inv# 1 | 2016-07-15 06:11:55   | 0       | 2016-07-15 | 147.25 | Unpaid
3  | #1 Payment For Inv# 3 | 2016-07-14 13:00:21   | 0       | 2016-07-18 | 4.58   | Unpaid
4  | #2 Payment For Inv# 3 | 2016-07-14 13:00:21   | 0       | 2016-07-21 | 4.58   | Unpaid
5  | #1 Payment For Inv# 2 | 2016-07-14 12:56:35   | 0       | 2016-07-22 | 50.00  | Unpaid
6  | #3 Payment For Inv# 1 | 2016-07-15 06:11:55   | 0       | 2016-07-22 | 147.25 | Unpaid
```

**cb_paymentscheduleheader**

```
id  |  installment_type
1   |  auto
2   |  auto
3   |  manual
```

**cb_paymentscheduleheader_cb_paymentscheduledetail_c**

```
id | cb_payment37a2eheader_ida | cb_paymente42dedetail_idb
1  | 1                         | 5
2  | 2                         | 6
3  | 2                         | 1
4  | 2                         | 2
5  | 3                         | 3
6  | 3                         | 4
```

**aos_invoices**

```
id | number | billing_account_id
1  | 1      | 1
2  | 2      | 2
3  | 3      | 3
```

**accounts**

```
id | phone_office | name
1  | 123          | a
2  | 123          | b
3  | 123          | c
```

**email_addr_bean_rel**

```
email_address_id | bean_id
1                | 1
2                | 2
3                | 3
```

**email_addresses**

```
id | email_address
1  | test@test.com
2  | test@test3.com
3  | test@test4.com
```

My Query:

```
SELECT cb_paymentscheduledetail.id , cb_paymentscheduledetail.amount , cb_paymentscheduledetail.assigned_user_id 
    ,MIN(cb_paymentscheduledetail.due_date) as min_date, cb_paymentscheduledetail.name, 
    cb_paymentscheduledetail.amount, aos_invoices.number, aos_invoices.billing_account_id,
    accounts.id as account_id, accounts.phone_office as account_phone, accounts.name as account_name, 
    email_addr_bean_rel.email_address_id, email_addr_bean_rel.bean_id, email_addresses.email_address as account_email, 
    cb_paymentscheduleheader_cb_paymentscheduledetail_c.id as headerdetail_id, 
    cb_paymentscheduleheader_cb_paymentscheduledetail_c.cb_paymente42dedetail_idb, 
    cb_paymentscheduleheader_cb_paymentscheduledetail_c.cb_payment37a2eheader_ida, cb_paymentscheduleheader.id as header_id, 
    cb_paymentscheduleheader.installment_type  
    FROM cb_paymentscheduledetail  
    LEFT JOIN aos_invoices ON aos_invoices.number = SUBSTRING_INDEX(cb_paymentscheduledetail.name, ' ', -1) 
    INNER JOIN accounts ON aos_invoices.billing_account_id = accounts.id 
    INNER JOIN email_addr_bean_rel ON accounts.id = email_addr_bean_rel.bean_id 
    INNER JOIN email_addresses ON email_addresses.id = email_addr_bean_rel.email_address_id  
    INNER JOIN cb_paymentscheduleheader_cb_paymentscheduledetail_c ON cb_paymentscheduledetail.id = cb_paymentscheduleheader_cb_paymentscheduledetail_c.cb_paymente42dedetail_idb  
    INNER JOIN cb_paymentscheduleheader ON cb_paymentscheduleheader_cb_paymentscheduledetail_c.cb_payment37a2eheader_ida = cb_paymentscheduleheader.id    
    WHERE cb_paymentscheduledetail.deleted = 0 AND cb_paymentscheduledetail.status = 'Unpaid' AND (cb_paymentscheduledetail.due_date BETWEEN '2016-07-15' AND '2016-07-22') 
    GROUP BY cb_paymentscheduledetail.date_entered 
    ORDER BY cb_paymentscheduledetail.due_date ASC;
```

My problem here is that the ID fetch by this query is not correct for amount **147.25** altough the min_date it fetch is correct:

the min_date queried is as follow:

```
4.58 = 2016-07-18
50.00 = 2016-07-22
147.25 = 2016-07-15
```

There ID should be this respectively:

```
4.58 = 3
50.00 = 5
147.25 = 2
```

But the actual ID is:

```
4.58 = 3
50.00 = 5
147.25 = 6
```

As you can see for amount "147.25" it is getting due_date 2016-07-22 when in the MIN function it got the correct one which is 2016-07-15, it is also getting the correct ID which should be 2 and not 6, Will anyone be able to help me with this as I cannot really see anymore what the problem is? since shouldn't it retrieve the appropriate ID based on my min_date when it got that correct from the start?

The only time 2016-07-15 is selected is when I change my BETWEEN to:

```
cb_paymentscheduledetail.due_date = '2016-07-15'
```

But I don't what this since I need to get the in between date

Comment: Can you create an SQL fiddle of your database, I don't think your `GROUP BY` statement does what you want it to do (alternatively, if you provide a sample SQL dump, I can run my ideas on my test machine)

Comment: Your query is against the sql standards and runs even in myqsl under certain sql mode setting only. There is nothing that would guarantee that the value of a column that it is neither in the group by list nor is subject to a grouping function (e.g. min()) will come from the same record as the value of the grouped column. You need to get the min(due_date) values in a subquery first and join this back on the main table.

Comment: @Shadow can you show me an example on how to do that?

Comment: Pls make a decent effort yourself first. You have @axiac 's excellent and lot more detailed answer to give you a head start. I honestly do not want to add a copy-paste answer that you would accept as a solution, since there is a lot better answer around that provides excellent guidance, instead of telling exactly how to achieve the desired output.

Comment: @Shadow I am trying to understand it but it is really confusing for me as I don't usually deal with this many relationships. I hope for your understanding, I am also playing around with the answer given to that link posted but I still can't get it to work when I customized it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> shouldn't it retrieve the appropriate ID based on my min_date when it got that correct from the start?

The short answer is **No**.

MySQL returns some values that seem random to you for all the expressions present in the `SELECT` clause that do not match one of the following:

- the expression is also present in the `GROUP BY` clause;
- the expression uses [`GROUP BY aggregate functions`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html);
- the expression is functionally dependent on the columns that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

It is a [documented behaviour](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and it is how it should be because of the way the `GROUP BY` works.

`GROUP BY` **does not** select rows from the database. It **generates** records using the values from the database. Each expression that appears in the `SELECT` clause of a query that also contains a `GROUP BY` clause is computed independent of the other expressions.

Think a little about it. Assuming it should work as you want, what values should the query return if you replace [`MIN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) with another [`GROUP BY aggregate function`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html)? With [`AVG()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg), for example. Most probably, there isn't any row in the `cb_paymentscheduledetail` table having in column `due_date` the value returned by `AVG(due_date)`. Or [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)? They doesn't even have the same type.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/4265352) provided on a similar question to learn the correct way to write a query that returns the row having the minimum/maximum value from its group in a certain column. It can be expanded to accommodate six tables by `INNER JOIN`-ing them with the table from which the row is selected (table `o` in that answer).

If you cannot handle it this way, you can split your query into two smaller queries (you can even merge them later using subqueries): one query on `paymentscheduledetail` that selects `MIN(due_date)` and groups by `date_entered` and another query that uses the value returned by the first query to select the desired row(s). Take into account that there can be more than one row that have in `due_date` the minimum value.

Comment: I'll be honest here and say that this is really confusing for me, I will take a look at the answer provided in that post, but will you be able to provide a sample layout on how to do a subquery with my current scenario? thank you

Comment: Very well written!

Comment: @Shadow It is but I'm still confused, for example, I tried the answer on that post and I wanted to add my additional where clause but it doesn't work as I would expect it to be. the where clause I added was to make sure that only due_date that is greater than the date today would be retrieved