# MySQL getting maximum of column with fallback to second column

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

```
+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| id   | user_id | obj_id | created | applied | content |
+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|    1 |       1 |      1 |       1 |       1 | ...     |
|    2 |       1 |      2 |       1 |       1 | ...     |
|    3 |       1 |      1 |       1 |       2 | ...     |
|    4 |       1 |      2 |       2 |       2 | ...     |
|    5 |       2 |      1 |       1 |       1 | ...     |
|    6 |       2 |      2 |       1 |       1 | ...     |
+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I have a table similar to the one above. `id`, `user_id` and `obj_id` are foreign keys; `created` and `applied` are timestamps stored as integers. I need to get the entire row, grouped by `user_id` and `obj_id`, with the maximum value of `applied`. If two rows have the same `applied` value, I need to favour the maximum value of `created`. So for the above data, my desired output is:

```
+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| id   | user_id | obj_id | created | applied | content |
+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|    1 |       1 |      1 |       1 |       1 | ...     |
|    4 |       1 |      2 |       2 |       2 | ...     |
|    5 |       2 |      1 |       1 |       1 | ...     |
|    6 |       2 |      2 |       1 |       1 | ...     |
+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

My current solution is to get everything ordered by `applied` then `created`:

```
select * from data order by applied desc created desc;
```

and sort things out in the code, but this table gets pretty big and I'd like an SQL solution that just gets the data I need.

Comment: ➕1 for the ASCII art; but for the sake of CVE: please add your initial query.

Comment: @LinusKleen How do you mean? The query I'm currently using, or the queries to replicate the above data?

Comment: Sorry. "Initial" as in: "the one that troubles you."

Comment: Do the fact you want group by  Which value do  you want select  for content .. ?

Comment: @scaisEdge The content is just some other fields; I'll take them out. I need a row for every user_id for every obj_id.

Comment: Consider the highest rated [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results), it should get you halfway there.

Comment: Thanks @MarkHeintz, that did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mark Heintz in the comments, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/2741954) got me to where I need to be.

```
SELECT
    data.id,
    data.user_id,
    data.obj_id,
    data.created,
    data.applied,
    data.content
FROM data
LEFT JOIN data next_max_applied ON
    next_max_applied.user_id = data.user_id AND
    next_max_applied.obj_id = data.obj_id AND (
        next_max_applied.applied > data.applied OR (
            next_max_applied.applied = data.applied AND
            next_max_applied.created > data.created
        )
    )
WHERE next_max_applied.applied IS NULL
GROUP BY user_id, obj_id;
```

Go read the answer for details on how it works; the `left join` tries to find a more recently applied row for the same user and object. If there isn't one, it will find a row applied at the same time, but created more recently.

The above means that any row without a more recent row to replace it will have a next_max_applied.applied value of null. These rows are filtered for by the `IS NULL` clause.

Finally, the `group by` clause handles any rows that have identical user, object, applied and created columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from my_table
where id in (
  /* inner subquery b */
  select max(id) 
      from my_table where 
      (user_id, obj_id, applied, created) in (
          /* inner subquery A */
          select user_id, obj_id, max(applied), max(created) 
          from my_table 
          group by user_id, obj_id
      )
);
```

Then inner subquery A return the (distinct) rows having  `user_id, obj_id, max(applied), max(created)`. Using these with in clause the subquery B retrive a list of  single ID each realated the a row with a proper value of user_id, obj_id, max(applied), max(created). so you have a collection of valid id for getting your result.

The main select use these ID for select the result you need.