# Get the newest record from each group

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-by

I want to sort the last messages with every user that a specific user has chated from ejabberd archive table.

The fields that I'm using are these

- `id` (message id)
- `username` (username copy)
- `bare_peer` (user that is chatting with)
- `txt` (text chat)
- `created_at` (time created)

What I'm trying to achieve is something like that, but I need to group message by `bare_peer` with username as `1_usernode`, but only the last messages.

I already tested a lot of queries, but none of them worked.
This is the first query I tried.

```
SELECT id, username, bare_peer, txt FROM archive where
username = '1_usernode' GROUP BY bare_peer ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

And this is the output.

```
+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| id   | username   | bare_peer              | txt                          | created_at          |
+------+------------+------------------------+------------------------------+---------------------+
| 1095 | 1_usernode | 10_usernode@localhost  | Hello !!!                    | 2016-07-17 21:15:17 |
| 1034 | 1_usernode | 15_usernode@localhost  | hey sup ?                    | 2016-07-13 22:40:29 |
| 1107 | 1_usernode | 13_usernode@localhost  | oi                           | 2016-07-18 00:09:28 |
| 1078 | 1_usernode | 2_usernode@localhost   | Hello this is just a Test!!! | 2016-07-15 16:30:50 |
| 1101 | 1_usernode | 7_usernode@localhost   | hey                          | 2016-07-18 00:05:55 |
| 1084 | 1_usernode | 3_usernode@localhost   | Hey how are you?             | 2016-07-15 19:36:44 |
| 1085 | 1_usernode | 4_usernode@localhost   | Hey how are you doing ?      | 2016-07-17 19:20:00 |
```

Comment: Is your created_at column set as the datetime datatype?

Comment: Since all of the `bare_peer` in your sample output are unique, it seems to have followed your query correctly.  Did you mean to group by `username`?

Comment: It would help if you showed the input data & your expected output. Maybe create an sql fiddle

Comment: The output is correct but it gives me the oldest messages what i need is the newest.

Comment: Your goal cannot be achieved using `GROUP BY` because `GROUP BY` does something else. It does not return rows from the database, it generates new rows using the data it extracts from the database. The query you posted is not valid SQL. Two (or more) different rows having the same value for `bare_peer` land in the same group. They have different values for `id` but you want to `SELECT id`. What `id`?

Comment: created_at is set as timestamp (current_timestamp)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/4265352). It solves the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :-

```
SELECT archive.id, archive.max_id, archive.username, archive.bare_peer, archive.txt 
FROM archive join 
(SELECT MAX(id) max_id, username, bare_peer, txt 
FROM archivewhere username = '1_usernode' GROUP BY bare_peer)
tab on archive.id=tab.max_id
```

Comment: It returns me the oldest messages but thanks anyway!

Comment: SELECT * FROM archive join 
(SELECT MAX(id) max_id, username, bare_peer, txt FROM archive 
where username = '1_usernode' GROUP BY bare_peer) tab
on archive.id=tab.max_id   try this query @RenatoCv

Comment: `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY` in the same query is not valid SQL.

Comment: the output returns me the time and id of the newest message that is correct combined with the text content of the older. it's almost working.

Comment: SELECT archive.id, archive.max_id, archive.username, archive.bare_peer, archive.txt 
FROM archive join 
(SELECT MAX(id) max_id, username, bare_peer, txt 
FROM archivewhere username = '1_usernode' GROUP BY bare_peer)
tab on archive.id=tab.max_id try this query @RenatoCv

Answer (score 0):

Use This Query It's Helful.

```
SELECT MAX(id), username, bare_peer, txt FROM archive where
username = '1_usernode' ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: Because of the implicit grouping (an aggregate function is used but no `GROUP BY` clause is present), this query returns a single row, rendering the `ORDER BY` clause useless (the query doesn't return the expected result, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

declare created_at as datetime

try this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `archive`;

CREATE TABLE `archive` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bare_peer` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `txt` TEXT,
  `created_at` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

/*Data for the table `archive` */

```
INSERT  INTO `archive`(`id`,`username`,`bare_peer`,`txt`,`created_at`) 
VALUES (1034,'1_usernode','15_usernode@localhost','hey sup ?','2016-07-13 22:40:29'),
(1078,'1_usernode','2_usernode@localhost','Hello this IS just a Test!!!','2016-07-15 16:30:50'),
(1084,'1_usernode','3_usernode@localhost','Hey how are you?','2016-07-15 19:36:44'),
(1085,'1_usernode','4_usernode@localhost','Hey how are you doing ?','2016-07-17 19:20:00'),
(1095,'1_usernode','10_usernode@localhost','Hello !!!','2016-07-17 21:15:17'),
(1101,'1_usernode','7_usernode@localhost','hey','2016-07-18 00:05:55'),
(1107,'1_usernode','13_usernode@localhost','oi','2016-07-18 00:09:28');
```

Then run your query

```
SELECT id, username, bare_peer, txt FROM archive where
username = '1_usernode' GROUP BY bare_peer ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

Comment: If i just modify the column in question, should it work anyway?

Comment: I created a second table called archive2 with your data and added more data with a earlier date. but it returns me always the oldest messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code:-

```
select m.*
from
messages m
inner join (
select max(id) as maxid
from messages
group By (if(username > bare_peer,  username, bare_peer)), 
(if(username > bare_peer,  bare_peer, username))
) t1 on m.id=t1.maxid ;
```

m is alias of message table

Answer (score 0):

You want the entry with max(created_at) for every username and bare_peer.
One way to do that in MySQL is with 'having' but I don't like that.
I would first get the max(created_at) for every entry:

```
select username, bare_peer, max(created_at) as m_
from archive
group by username, bare_peer;
```

Then join the table on that result:

```
select b.*
from (
    select username, bare_peer, max(created_at) as m_
    from archive
    group by username, bare_peer
) a
inner join archive as b on (
    a.username = b.username
    and a.bare_peer = b.bare_peer
    and a.m_ = b.created_at
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to know why it shows the created_at column when you don't select created_at? And I don't know why you use `group by`? There is nothing need to be divided into groups.

My statement looks like this.`select id, username, bare_peer, txt, created_at from archive where username = '1_usercode' order by created_at desc`

Comment: i mistakenly deleted created_at from the original query.

Answer (score 0):

I created a temporary solution with the Rahauto's answer.
I put his query that returns me the correct id from latest message inside a
subquery so that i can extract message content from  it's id.

```
SELECT username, bare_peer, txt, created_at FROM archive WHERE id IN (
  SELECT tab.max_id  FROM
    archive JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) max_id, username, bare_peer, txt FROM
    archive WHERE username = '1_usernode' GROUP BY bare_peer)
  tab ON archive.id=tab.max_id
);
```