# MIN and GROUP BY wrong id

Tags: mysql

I got a (guess) really simple question here. I use the query below, to get the lowest prices of some objects. I get the lowest price but the price id (pid) is not the one of the lowest price but another one.

What should i do to get the right pid too?

---

Table

```
pid, oid, price
1, 10, 300
2, 10, 400
3, 10, 500
4, 20, 310
5, 20, 410
6, 20, 510
```

---

Query

```
SELECT  pid, oid, min(price)
FROM prices
group by oid
```

Comment: *"What should i do to get the right pid too?"* -- write the correct query. `GROUP BY` cannot be used for that. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/4265352) provided to a similar query to get an idea how to work it out.

Comment: This one got me the solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column

Comment: @axiac The question was a bit unclear, hence my editing the answer several times.