# laravel, group by category and select the record with the minimum price

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have models `Book` and `BookCategory`

How do I select the cheapest book in every category?

Book table:

```
| id | name | price | book_category_id |  
| 1 | test | 10 | 1  
| 2 | test | 15 | 3  
| 3 | test | 75 | 1  
| 4 | test | 25 | 2  
| 5 | test | 19 | 1  
| 6 | test | 11 | 2  
| 7 | test | 10 | 1
```

The selection should be :

```
| id | name | price | book_category_id |  
| 1 | test | 10 | 1  
| 2 | test | 15 | 3  
| 6 | test | 11 | 2
```

I've tried:

```
$books = Book::groupBy("book_category_id")->orderBy("price")->get()
```

But the output is not the minimum price row.

any idea?

EDIT:

I found this page:
https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

it has 90% of the solution in SQL

```
    SELECT *
    FROM books
    WHERE price = (SELECT MIN(price) FROM books AS u WHERE u.book_category_id= books.book_category_id)
GROUP BY books.book_category_id
```

how to convert this to laravel query builder?

Comment: What is the result of the code you supplied?

Comment: its getting the first record of every group, in my this case it's getting books of id: 1,2,and 4

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a subquery like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12102288/7377984). Try this:

```
$books = Book::from(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM books order by price asc"))
             ->groupBy("book_category_id")->get();
```

Please note that this is a mysql only solution because in mysql you're allowed to not aggregate non-group-by columns. If you need to do this for another DB, you need to perform an inner join on the subquery

Comment: this return exactly like my code. it return the first record of every group + extra filed min_price. (the min_price, is not necessary the price of the returned record

Comment: still , even with rearranging, the result is not the minimum record

Comment: What is the result? Did you use the exact code? And is your DB mysql?

Comment: Oops, there was a typo, try the updated code. Note the change from `desc` to `asc`

Comment: Okay, what is the result in that case and are you using mysql?

Comment: i updated the question with something that may help, check that out please

Comment: Dont think the query you posted is the most optimal. I would say this query would be the best: `select * from (select * from books order by price) group by book_category_id`. You can try it in mysql. If you post the output of my answer, I can try to help

Comment: relying on "group by" and order is not reliable, you cannot control which row "group by" select

Comment: This query is guaranteed to give the min price. The query you have mentioned will also give min price row. Both queries don't guarantee which row to return if 2 rows have same price