# Left join SQL tables and get value of most recent row

Tags: mysql, sql

I've an SQL statement that I've been dealing with for a while now.

How do I get the most recent (by date, and then id) weight-value from another table. This is my query so far:

```
SELECT e.name, e.picture_url, e.id AS exercise_id, w.parent_id, e.video_url,
        w.id, w.comment, w.time, w.reps, w.rest, w.sets, wt.name as wtype,
        w.order_by, mg.name as muscle_group, eq.name as equipment, w_track.*
        FROM workout w
        LEFT JOIN exercises e
        ON e.id = w.exercise_id
        LEFT JOIN workout_types wt
        ON wt.id = e.workout_type_id
        LEFT JOIN muscle_groups mg
        ON e.muscle_group_id = mg.id
        LEFT JOIN equipments eq
        ON eq.id = e.equipment_id

        LEFT JOIN (SELECT workout_id, weight FROM workout_tracking GROUP BY workout_id ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC) w_track
        ON w.id = w_track.workout_id


        WHERE workout_day_id = 395
```

I want to left join workout_tracking and get the most recent 'weight' value - the row with the newest date and highest id.

Thanks in advance!
All help appreciated!

**UPDATE**
When I run the above query I get some random 'weight' number, and not the most recent one.

The 'workout' table consists of:
- id (primary key for workout_tracking)
- workout_day_id (foreign key for 'workout_day'
- reps
- rest 
- sets 
- etc...

The 'workout_tracking' table consists of:
- id
- workout_id (workout-table foreign key)
- weight
- date

**Sample data**
'workout'-table:

```
  +---+------------+-------------+
  |id |     sets   |    reps     |
  +---+------------+-------------+
  | 1 |      3     |     10
```

'workout_tracking'-table:

```
  +---+------------+-------------+-------------+
  |id | workout_id |    weight   |    date
  +---+------------+-------------+-------------+
  | 1 |      1     |     10        2017-05-22
    2        1           12        2017-05-28
    3        1           14        2017-05-28
    4        1           11        2017-05-28
    5        1          NULL       2017-05-28
    6        1          NULL       2017-05-28
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I guess your problem is with the `SELECT workout_id, weight FROM workout_tracking GROUP BY workout_id` ??

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes exactly

Comment: What is the difference between `workout_id` and `id` in the `workout_tracking` table?...with that info I can help you adding `max` to the query based on the right field.

Comment: `id` is the id of the workout_tracking row, and workout_id is the foreign key for table `workout`

Comment: Check this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results

Comment: Do you really need order by id and date? isnt the latest id the latest date?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I guess it will work only by id at first :)

Comment: Show us some sample data, only for that `workout_tracking` table

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza done

Comment: So again what weigth you want? Because you order by id and date? Do you have different weitght on same day? Try to add morer data with same day and tell us what result you expect.

Comment: I've added more data. I want to get the 11 in `weight`, the weight of the most recent date, with the highest id :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is using variables:

[**SQL DEMO**](http://rextester.com/XXBB4431)

```
SELECT `id`, `workout_id`, `weight`, `date`,
       @rn := IF( @workout_id = `workout_id`,
                  @rn + 1,
                  IF(@workout_id := `workout_id`, 1, 1)
                ) as rn
FROM workout_tracking     
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @workout_id := -1) as var
ORDER BY `workout_id`, `date` DESC, `id` DESC
```

Because you order first for `workout_id` you can find the latest `date` and latest `id`, in this case those will have `@rn = 1`

Now your final query should be

```
SELECT w.*, filter.*
FROM workout w
JOIN (SELECT `id`, `workout_id`, `weight`, `date`,
              @rn := IF( @workout_id = `workout_id`,
                         @rn + 1,
                         IF(@workout_id := `workout_id`, 1, 1)
                       ) as rn
      FROM workout_tracking     
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @workout_id := -1) as var
      ORDER BY `workout_id`, `date` DESC, `id` DESC
     ) as filter
 ON w.id = filter.`workout_id`
WHERE filter.rn = 1;
```

For `LEFT JOIN` try:

```
LEFT JOIN ( ... ) as filter
  ON w.id = filter.`workout_id`
 AND filter.rn = 1
```

dont need the where condition.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but sequel pro can't run this query - it says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@rn + 1,
                         IF(@workout_id := `workout_id`, 1, 1)
        ' at line 5"

Comment: I miss a comma, try again

Comment: Check the Live Demo example.

Comment: wow Juan well done, there is only one more thing - now it doesn't include the exercises that don't have any workout_tracking rows associated with them. I've tried to do LEFT JOIN instead of just regular JOIN in your query

Comment: It still doesn't include the exercises without workout_tracking rows, when I do a left join.

Comment: Awesome Juan! One last thing, can you also do so if in case the weight of most recent row is NULL, we pick the weight of the most recent row that is not NULL :)?

Comment: mmmm I dont see how is that possible, show me an example. You can edit the rextester demo with additional data, Fork it and send me the link.

Comment: Do you mean `weight` can be null? In that case just filter `WHERE weight IS NOT NULL` in the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(workout_id) AS workout_id, weight FROM workout_tracking GROUP BY workout_id ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC) w_track ON w.id = w_track.workout_id

Comment: Hi zarif, I tried your query, but it still gives me some random weight, which is not the most recent