# Optimized mysql queries in mysql database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to fetch 3 `rows` data from `class` table who is belongs to class `5,6 and 7` last row only.

Right now I'm using 3 `sql` queries to fetch data:

```
 1. SELECT * from class where class_name = '5';

 2. SELECT * from class where class_name = '6';

 3. SELECT * from class where class_name = '7';
```

How can I use single sql query to retrieve 3 row data instead of 3 sql queries ?

```
**class table structure:**

|id | class_name | student  |
|---| -----------| ---------| 
|1  |      5     | Student A|
|2  |      6     | Student B|
|3  |      4     | Student C|
|4  |      6     | Student D|
|5  |      7     | Student E|
|6  |      5     | Student F|
|7  |      4     | Student G|
|8  |      6     | Student H|
|9  |      5     | Student I|
|10 |      6     | Student J|
|11 |      7     | Student K|
|12 |      6     | Student L|
|13 |      8     | Student M|
|14 |      6     | Student N|
|15 |      8     | Student O|
```

**Result required:**
Student I,Student N and Student K

Comment: i have update my answer....with sqlfiddle

Comment: This is the most frequently asked question under this tag. Occasionally, it's correctly answered too. For a definitive solution, please refer to the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM class WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM class WHERE class_name in (5,6,7) GROUP BY class_name );
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/529058/7)

Comment: I want only last row who belongs to class 5, class 6, class 7.
above sql query will not return data if class 5 and 6 doesn't have data.

Comment: result should be Student I,Student N and Student K

Comment: in this query we used `OR` condition.. this query retrieve data 5 or 6 or 7 class..

Comment: first you correct id (1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2...) its not true.. id should have (1,2,3,4,5.....)

Comment: I need only 1 records with class 5 and class 6 and class 7
result will be Student I,Student N and Student K
Is this possible ?

Comment: you mention the desire result in your question

Answer (score 0):

`select * from (select * from class order by id desc, class_name) x group by class_name`

Comment: That's return all data of sql queries.
I want only last row who belongs to class 5, class 6, class 7

Comment: please try this -

SELECT * from class where class_name in (5, 6, 7) order by id DESC limit 1;

Comment: not working, because indexing will return only last record in table
result will be Student I,Student N and Student K

Comment: Do you want last 3 rows totally ? First one will be of class 5, second of 6 & last of 7 ?

Comment: I want class 5 last row data, class 6 last row data, class 7 last row data.
result will be Student I,Student N and Student K according to table

Comment: Okay, now got your question. Please update it this way.

Comment: if it doesn't work, please refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results

Comment: your latest answer is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from (SELECT * from class ORDER BY id  DESC) t WHERE class_name in (5,6,7) GROUP BY class_name ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: can you explain what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery since `GROUP BY` cannot be used with a wildcard. Instead you have to group by every column that you select.

```
SELECT * FROM class
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM class
    WHERE class_name IN (5, 6, 7) GROUP BY class_name ORDER BY id DESC
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM class 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(ID) 
    FROM dbo.class 
    WHERE class_name IN (5,6,7) 
    GROUP BY class_name )
```

This should do the trick, tested and here's the result:

```
id          class_name student
----------- ---------- --------------------
1           5          A                   
2           6          B                   
3           4          C                   
4           6          D                   
5           7          E                   
6           5          F                   
7           4          G                   
8           6          H                   
9           5          I                   
10          6          J                   
11          7          K                   
12          6          L                   
13          8          M                   
14          6          N                   
15          8          O                   

(15 row(s) affected)

id          class_name student
----------- ---------- --------------------
9           5          I                   
11          7          K                   
14          6          N                   

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * from class where class_name = '5' or class_name = '6' or class_name = '7'