# How can I exclude duplicates from this SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the data in the invoicehistory table.

```
invoicehistoryID WorkOrderNumber InvoiceDate

1                1               2017-06-13 12:00:49
2                1               2017-06-13 12:05:05
3                10              2017-06-14 12:32:59
4                10              2017-06-14 14:26:25
5                1               2017-06-14 14:26:54
6                1               2017-06-22 10:12:49
```

What SELECT query do I need to get only the latest InvoiceDate for each WorkOrderNumber, ordered by WorkOrderNumber?  In other words, how can I get this:

```
invoicehistoryID WorkOrderNumber InvoiceDate
6                1               2017-06-22 10:12:49
4                10              2017-06-14 14:26:25
```

I haven't had success with DISTINCT.  I haven't had success with LIMIT because my invoicehistory table will grow.

This almost works,

```
SELECT max(InvoiceDate),WorkOrderNumber FROM `invoicehistory` GROUP BY WorkOrderNumber
```

but doesn't get the invoicehistoryID.
This

```
SELECT max(InvoiceDate),WorkOrderNumber, invoicehistoryID FROM `invoicehistory` GROUP BY WorkOrderNumber, invoicehistoryID
```

returns all of the rows.

Comment: _...What SELECT query do I need to get..._ What queries have you tried so far?

Comment: Think of data in terms of sets.  you need the MAX(Invoicedate) for each work order number.  This represents the set (A) you're after; but you need additional information (invoicehistoryID); which can be obtained by JOINING this set (A) back to your base set from invoicehistory. on the ordernumber and that invoice date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get records with max value for each group of grouped SQL results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results)

Comment: Have you tried with a Distinct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Set D: is the max invoice date per work order.
- Set IH is the entire Invoice history.

By Joining D to IH on the date and order nubmer we can get the missing invoicehistoryID and other information if needed.

```
SELECT IH.invoiceHistoryID, IH.WorkOrderNumber, IH.InvoiceDate
FROM InvoiceHistory IH
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(invoiceDate) mInvoiceDate, WorkOrderNumber
            FROM invoicehistory
            GROUP BY workorderNumber) D
 on D.mInvoiceDate = IH.InvoiceDate
and D.WorkOrderNumber = IH.workOrderNumber
```

Cross apply would be another way to achieve this if mySQL supported it

or use of window functions to assign a row number and limit the results to the newest date if mySQL supported them.

Comment: Thank you. That wasn't exactly right, but it pointed me in the right direction.  I ended up doing:
`SELECT IH.WorkOrderNumber, IH.invoicehistoryID, IH.InvoiceDate
FROM invoicehistory as IH
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(invoiceDate) as maxInvoiceDate, WorkOrderNumber
            FROM invoicehistory
            GROUP BY workorderNumber) IH2
 ON IH2.maxInvoiceDate = IH.InvoiceDate
AND IH2.WorkOrderNumber = IH.workOrderNumber
ORDER BY IH.WorkOrderNumber ASC`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT invoicehistoryID, WorkOrderNumber, InvoiceDate
FROM (SELECT invoicehistoryID, WorkOrderNumber, InvoiceDate
  FROM TABLE
  ORDER BY WorkOrderNumber ASC, InvoiceDate DESC
) inv
GROUP BY WorkOrderNumber
```

Comment: Nope. I get "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY WorkOrderNumber LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, GROUP should be before ORDER. Also I noticed that, then, it will not work as said. Edited and try again.

`SELECT invoicehistoryID, WorkOrderNumber, InvoiceDate
FROM (SELECT invoicehistoryID, WorkOrderNumber, InvoiceDate
  FROM TABLE
  ORDER BY WorkOrderNumber ASC, InvoiceDate DESC
) inv
GROUP BY WorkOrderNumber`

Comment: Still no. "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'inv.invoicehistoryID' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"
I already got xQbert's answer to work, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice mySql until I had the answer in ms sql:

```
 CREATE TABLE #tmp(
    InvoiceHistoryID  INT,
    WorkOrderNumber INT,
    InvoiceDate datetime
    )

   INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(1,1,'2017-06-13 12:00:49')
   INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(2,1,'2017-06-13 12:05:05')
   INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(3,10,'2017-06-14 12:32:59')
   INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(4,10,'2017-06-14 12:32:59')
   INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(5,1,'2017-06-14 14:26:54')
   INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(6,1,'2017-06-22 10:12:49')


    SELECT 
       t.InvoiceHistoryID,
       t.WorkOrderNumber,
       m.InvoiceDate
    FROM #tmp t JOIN (SELECT MAX(InvoiceHistoryID) AS  InvoiceHistoryID, 
                             MAX(InvoiceDate) AS InvoiceDate
                    FROM #tmp 
                    GROUP BY WorkOrderNumber ) AS m 
    ON t.InvoiceHistoryID = m.InvoiceHistoryID                  

    DROP TABLE #tmp
```