# Get record with min value of a group

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do the opposite of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results)

I need to get the minimum value out of a grouped record, so, taking the same information from the linked question, from

```
ID | Person | Group | Age
---
1  | Bob    | 1     | 32  
2  | Jill   | 1     | 34  
3  | Shawn  | 1     | 42  
4  | Jake   | 2     | 29  
5  | Tom    | 2     | 28  
6  | Paul   | 2     | 36  
7  | Laura  | 2     | 39  
8  | Julie  | 2     | 28
```

Desired result set:

```
1  | Bob    | 1     | 32    
5  | Tom    | 2     | 28
```

I tried by joining the table on herself with opposite condition (< instead of >) but it's not working.

Duplicates are not allowed, if two persons have the same age, the one with the lowest ID has to be returned.

Comment: Note that group is a reserved word, making it a decidedly poor choice for a column identifier. (And - unless it's a table of the deceased - you don't really store age, do you!!)

Comment: Well I just copied the example provided in the linked question. I know it's a reserved word.

Comment: Is the 4,4 intentional?

Comment: Copypaste error, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

I would do this using `where` and a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*
from persons p
where p.age = (select min(p2.age) from persons p2 where p2.group = p.group);
```

or:

```
select p.*
from persons p
where p.age = (select p2.age
               from persons p2
               where p2.group = p.group
               order by p2.age desc
               limit 1
              );
```

This easily extends to multiple keys by using `id`:

```
select p.*
from persons p
where p.id = (select p2.id
               from persons p2
               where p2.group = p.group
               order by p2.age desc, id asc
               limit 1
              );
```

Comment: What's the main difference between this and joining the table itself? Different performance?

Comment: @Cusy For something like this there isn't much difference between this and a self-join. Performance should be the same, since the optimizer will take over and rewrite in the more efficient manner. For a short subquery like this it comes down to readability on whether to keep as is or convert to a self-join.

Comment: @Cusy . . . I find that this is easier to follow.  In MySQL and other databases, I think the performance of the two should be similar, particularly with an index on `persons(group, age)`.

Comment: It still retrieves duplicates (IE: add another person in group 2 with 29 years). Any way to filter those out?

Comment: @Cusy Edit your question with the result you are now receiving.

Comment: Edited with more information. This should also avoid the "Group by" wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way (I renamed one of the columns in order to preserve my sanity):

```
    SELECT a.* 
      FROM my_table a 
      JOIN 
         ( SELECT MIN(id) id 
             FROM my_table x 
             JOIN 
                ( SELECT group_id, MIN(age) age FROM my_table GROUP BY group_id) y 
               ON y.group_id = x.group_id 
              AND y.age = x.age 
            GROUP 
               BY x.group_id
                , x.age
         ) b 
        ON b.id = a.id;
```