# using MAX() and GROUP BY is not returning correct result

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Here is my DB.

```
id - date_time             - barcode_no - result
1  - '2017-08-01 01:00:00' - 'A'        - '1'
2  - '2017-08-01 02:00:00' - 'A'        - '2'
31 - '2017-08-01 03:00:00' - 'A'        - '3'
4  - '2017-08-01 04:00:00' - 'B'        - '4'
5  - '2017-08-01 05:00:00' - 'B'        - '5'
61 - '2017-08-01 06:00:00' - 'B'        - '6'
7  - '2017-08-01 07:00:00' - 'C'        - '7'
8  - '2017-08-01 08:00:00' - 'C'        - '8'
9  - '2017-08-01 09:00:00' - 'C'        - '9'
100- '2017-08-01 10:00:00' - 'C'        - '10'
```

I have this query on mySQL

```
SELECT barcode_no,MAX(date_time),result
FROM test_data_main 
GROUP BY barcode_no
```

but it does not give me the correct result. I also used the any_value(result) but I get the same wrong result.

Here is the link for my sample DB and code on SQL Fiddle.
[SAMPLE CODE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ed5a7/2/0)

My requirement is to get the row of the latest barcode_no.

```
id - date_time             - barcode_no - result
31 - '2017-08-01 03:00:00' - 'A'        - '3'
61 - '2017-08-01 06:00:00' - 'B'        - '6'
100- '2017-08-01 10:00:00' - 'C'        - '10'
```

but my wrong result was

```
id - date_time             - barcode_no - result
31 - '2017-08-01 03:00:00' - 'A'        - '1'
61 - '2017-08-01 06:00:00' - 'B'        - '4'
100- '2017-08-01 10:00:00' - 'C'        - '7'
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my query. Please advise. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"My requirement is to get the row of the latest barcode_no."* -- You cannot get rows from the table using `GROUP BY`. `GROUP BY` computes new rows using the data from the table. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/4265352) on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12102200/4265352).

Comment: Thank you both axiac and Sagar Gangwal. Seems to be similar axiac. To bad it did not show when searched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT test_data_main.* FROM test_data_main
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT barcode_no,MAX(date_time) date_time
  FROM test_data_main 
  GROUP BY barcode_no
)Z ON Z.barcode_no=test_data_main.barcode_no AND Z.date_time=test_data_main.date_time
```

You can try above code.

You can check here: [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ed5a7/5)