# Selecting the last entry from each group in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I am very new to MySQL (I tried groupby, but didnt get the result) This my sample data

```
ticket year status data
111    2007 1      32
111    2007 2      46
111    2007 3      40
111    2007 4      38
111    2009 1      15
111    2009 2      12
115    2009 1      2 
115    2009 2      5
```

I want to select the last entry for each company, for each year. Output should be:

```
ticket year status data
111    2007 4      38 
111    2009 2      12
115    2009 2      5
```

Comment: You should be able to get it with a group by , can you show what you did?

Comment: You **cannot** select rows using `GROUP BY`. `GROUP BY` computes new rows using the data from each group. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/4265352) on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12102200/4265352).

Answer (score 0):

as status field values looks incremental order. we can simply apply max after groupby.

```
select a.* from a 
inner join (select ticket,year,max(status) as sta from a group by ticket,year) as b 
on a.status=b.sta 
and a.ticket=b.ticket and a.year=b.year;
```

Comment: Updated the question. This is what I had tried. I need to select the row which is corresponding to max(status)