# Grouping by aggregate function max in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

I have the table instructor as follows:

```sql
+-------+------------+------------+----------+
| ID    | name       | dept_name  | salary   |
+-------+------------+------------+----------+
| 10101 | Srinivasan | Comp. Sci. | 65000.00 |
| 12121 | Wu         | Finance    | 90000.00 |
| 15151 | Mozart     | Music      | 40000.00 |
| 22222 | Einstein   | Physics    | 95000.00 |
| 32343 | El Said    | History    | 60000.00 |
| 33456 | Gold       | Physics    | 87000.00 |
| 45565 | Katz       | Comp. Sci. | 75000.00 |
| 58583 | Califieri  | History    | 62000.00 |
| 76543 | Singh      | Finance    | 80000.00 |
| 76766 | Crick      | Biology    | 72000.00 |
| 83821 | Brandt     | Comp. Sci. | 92000.00 |
| 98345 | Kim        | Elec. Eng. | 80000.00 |
+-------+------------+------------+----------+
```

The query

```sql
 select dept_name, max(salary) from instructor group by dept_name;
```

will give me the max salary for each department in the instructor.

However, I want to get all the columns in the result, that is also *ID* and *name* of the highest paid instructor in each department. But I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: This type of question has been answered many times here in SO. If you search for *greatest per group mysql* you will get plenty of examples.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos [This is the usual duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results) folks are marking with.  But, the accepted answer is terrible IMO, and you really have to scroll down a while to find something which looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your current query as a subquery which filters the original table:

```
SELECT i1.*
FROM instructor i1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT dept_name, MAX(salary) AS salary
    FROM instructor
    GROUP BY dept_name
) i2
    ON i1.dept_name = i2.dept_name AND i1.salary = i2.salary;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query:

```
SELECT ID, name, dept_name, salary
FROM( select ID, name, dept_name, salary, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  dept_name ORDER BY salary DESC) as ranks
 from instructor)T
 WHERE ranks = 1
```

Comment: Note: This query would only run on MySQL versions 8+ or later.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use correlated sub-query

```
select t.* from instructor  t
 where salary in
  ( 
    select  max(salary) from instructor t1 
    where t1.dept_name=t.dept_name
    group by t1.dept_name 
   )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7018c/1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ins.id , ins.name 
FROM instructor ins 
inner join (
    SELECT ins2.id as id , MAX(ins2.salary) as salary 
    FROM instructor ins2 
    group by ins2.id
) as insG 
ON ins.id = insG.id AND ins.salary = insG.salary
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery :

```
select i.*
from instructor i
where salary = (select max(i1.salary)
                from instructor i1
                where i1.dept_name = i.dept_name
               );
```