# how to restrict SQL Left JOIN to only return the latest record of the secondary table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two tables (**documents** and **states**). 
**documents** fields:

```
id,      (int)
document,(string)
file,    (string)
creation (date)
```

**states** fields:

```
id,          (int)
id_document, (int)
status,      (string)
last_update  (date)
```

*id_document* obviously match *id* in the first table.

The first table holds data related to documents and the second an updated serie of states of the processing of documents of the first table. 
I need to create a view to show the list of documents with, **only**, their last reached status, if any.

I wrote this query but that make the correct join but I'm unable to restrict it to the last status:

```
SELECT
 documents.*, states.status, states.last_update  
FROM
 documents
LEFT JOIN states ON states.id = documents.id
ORDER BY states.last_update
```

I tried with DISTINCT, DISTINCTROW but without luck....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get records with max value for each group of grouped SQL results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results)

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: @jarlh MySQL 8.0.13

Answer (score 1):

This should provide what you are looking for (there may exist a more elegant solution):

```
  select d.*,
         s.status, 
         s.last_update
  from   documents d,
         states s
  where  s.id = d.id
  and    s.last_update = ( select last_update
                           from   states
                           where  id = d.id
                           order by last_update desc
                           limit 0,1 )
  or     s.last_update is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
SELECT
 documents.*, updates .status, updates.updated 
FROM
 documents
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_document, status, MAX(last_update) AS updated 
           FROM states 
           GROUP BY id_document) AS updates 
     ON states.id = documents.id
ORDER BY states.last_update
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query with max(last_status) per document. Then inner join the sub-query to your query on document and last_status.