# mysql - Get records with max value for each group of grouped SQL results

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I´m refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results) post from Yarin in 2012.

this won't work anymore, im using mysql v 8.0.19

Given a table like that below, with person, group, and age columns, how would you get the oldest person in each group? (A tie within a group should give the first alphabetical result)

```
Person | Group | Age
---
Bob  | 1     | 32  
Jill | 1     | 34  
Shawn| 1     | 42  
Jake | 2     | 29  
Paul | 2     | 36  
Laura| 2     | 39
```

Desired result set:

```
Shawn | 1     | 42    
Laura | 2     | 39
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by group order by age desc, person) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

The accepted answer to the linked post baffles me somehow. It relies on option `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` being disabled (well, ok, that was the default in MySQL 5.6). It makes assumptions about the way MySQL behaves in that case, which I don't think are officially documented anywhere. I wouldn't recmmend that, even in MySQL 5.6; happily, there is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/10676716), with more upvotes, that seem like a much safer approach to the question.

Comment: that was fast! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way for example

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `Person` VARCHAR(5),
>   `Group` INTEGER,
>   `Age` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`Person`, `Group`, `Age`)
> VALUES
>   ('Bob', '1', '32'),
>   ('Jill', '1', '34'),
>   ('Shawn', '1', '42'),
>   ('Jake', '2', '29'),
>   ('Paul', '2', '36'),
>   ('Laura', '2', '39');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `Person`, `Group`, `Age` FROM table1 s1 WHERE   `Age`=(SELECT MAX(s2.`Age`)
>               FROM table1 s2
>               WHERE s1.`Group` = s2.`Group`)
> ```

> ```
> Person | Group | Age
> :----- | ----: | --:
> Shawn  |     1 |  42
> Laura  |     2 |  39
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b24cd3da70c34006fdcb9f5a78ab593)*