# Choosing highest value in a GROUP BY Join

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a `pages` table of URLs and the categories they're associated with. I'm joining it with ITSELF using a `constraints` table and using `GROUP BY` to get unique URLs, then sorting by highest score.

Problem: The highest score of the group of URLs isn't always selected.

(Background: In production, this will be used to know which pages in the 'from' category should hyperlink to pages in the 'to' category)

I think there is something in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12102258/303860), but I can't figure out how to adapt it:

### Current Query

```sql
SELECT keyword, URL, score FROM
    (   
        SELECT keyword, URL, score
        FROM pages
        JOIN constraints
        ON pages.category = constraints.to
        AND constraints.from IN (SELECT category FROM pages WHERE URL = 'https://www.example.net')
        ORDER BY score DESC
    )   
AS x        
GROUP BY URL;
```

### pages

```sql
+---------+-------------------------+----------+-------+
| keyword | URL                     | category | score |
+---------+-------------------------+----------+-------+
| Cat     | https://www.example.org | 1        | 100   |
+---------+-------------------------+----------+-------+
| Dog     | https://www.example.com | 2        | 50    |
+---------+-------------------------+----------+-------+
| Fish    | https://www.example.com | 2        | 60    |
+---------+-------------------------+----------+-------+
| Mouse   | https://www.example.net | 3        | 1     |
+---------+-------------------------+----------+-------+
```

### constraints

```sql
+------+----+
| from | to |
+------+----+
| 1    | 2  |
+------+----+
| 2    | 1  |
+------+----+
| 3    | 2  |
+------+----+
```

### Current output:

```sql
+---------+-------------------------+-------+
| keyword | URL                     | score |
+---------+-------------------------+-------+
| Dog     | https://www.example.com | 50    |
+---------+-------------------------+-------+
```

Dog row selected, despite having a lower score than the Fish row.

### Desired output:

```sql
+---------+-------------------------+-------+
| keyword | URL                     | score |
+---------+-------------------------+-------+
| Fish    | https://www.example.com | 60    |
+---------+-------------------------+-------+
```

Edit: Reduced tables to a minimal reproducible example. Added current output. And explained things a little better.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: Please describe how you got to your 'desired output'. (In other word, doen let someone else guess or assume)

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, I thought I had made it minimal, but I will try again

Comment: I'm just lost.  You have "4" in the constraints table, but it is not in your data.  You specify that for some URL what want others -- but what URL are the results based on?

Comment: Great. Let us know when you do.

Comment: @Strawberry - Thanks, I've updated the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Apologies, have now simplified the question to bare bones.

Comment: @Luuk Thanks, take a look at the revised question

Comment: Hm, I'd refer you again to the linked answer at my original comment.

Comment: @Strawberry I think only thing missing is the INSERT statements?

Comment: INSERT statements are indeed one thing that are missing. They are not the only thing that is missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225261/discussion-between-jon-and-strawberry).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data, I tried working out the problem.
My logic is as follows :

1. I started building a denormalized table, which is `table x`, which contains information on page traversal, i.e *from pages* & *to pages* also with respective URLs.
2. In `table y`,  using `dense_rank()` function can help in *ranking* your results.
3. From `table y`, only *rank 1* records have to be picked & to remove duplicates `group by` is used.

my query is as follows :

```
select to_keyword as Keyword, to_url as URL, to_score as Score 
    from (
     select from_url, to_keyword, to_url, to_score, dense_rank() over (partition by to_url order by to_score desc) as rnk 
       from ( select p.url as from_url, u.Keyword as to_keyword, u.url as to_url, u.Category as to_category, u.Score as to_score 
              from pages p inner join constrains c on p.Category = c.from inner join pages u on u.Category = c.to
             )x
         ) y 
    where rnk = 1 and from_url = 'https://www.b.com/' 
    group by 1, 2, 3
    order by to_url
```