# How to select only one data from duplicate data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have table `bio`

```
ID   Name    Country   Address
1    Dan     America    A
2    Dan     Japan      B
3    Dan     Canada     C
4    Marcus  China      D
5    Kurtis  Nepal      E
6    Kurtis  Mexico     F
7    Jack    Indonesia  G
```

I need to select only one from the duplicate value of column "Name". I expect the result like this.

```
ID   Name    Country   Address
1    Dan     America    A
4    Marcus  China      D
5    Kurtis  Nepal      E
7    Jack    Indonesia  G
```

I used this query

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = ( SELECT REPLACE ( @@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', '' ) );
Select * from bio group by name;
```

Is there any other way without using `SET SESSION sql_mode = ( SELECT REPLACE ( @@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', '' ) );` since if i didn't use that, it return error.

I have tried answer with `forpass` answer but it run very slow. Here is the `Explain` query.

```
id  select_type         table   type    possible_keys   rows    filtered Extra
1   PRIMARY             b       ALL                     1095012  100.00  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  t       ALL     PRIMARY,semua   1095012  3.33    Range checked for each record (index map: 0x3)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get records with max value for each group of grouped SQL results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results).

Comment: Please check the above link for some options.  This question gets asked several times per day on this site.

Comment: *I need to select only one from the duplicate value of column "Name"* which one? What is the logig behind the expected result?

Comment: in my table i have 3 duplicate value "Dan" in column name. I need to select only one data from the 3 duplicate value. same with Value "Kurtis" there are two duplicate value. I need to take only one data from 2 duplicate data of "Kurtis". @Jens

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy mysql 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM bio b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM bio t
  WHERE t.Name = b.Name AND t.ID < b.ID
)
```

Comment: i have 1 million data, it run really slow to return the result even i have indexed the table.

Comment: @Gagantous in MySql 5.7, without window functions, there aren't many options for this requiremnet. Either you use NOT EXISTS or aggregation and a join (which normally is less efficient than NOT EXISTS), or a simulation of row_number like Arun's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily achieved in MySQL 8.0 using the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY )` window function. But in `5.7` you have to emulate the same function with variables. Something like below.

```
SELECT ID, Name, Country, Address
FROM (
    SELECT *, IF (@prev <> name, @rn: = 0, @rn),
        @prev: = Name,
        @rn: = @rn + 1 AS rn
    FROM bio, 
          (SELECT @rn: = 0 ) rn, 
          (SELECT @prev: = '') prev
    ORDER BY Address ASC
    ) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Alternatively you can use `simple join` to avoid mentioning the column names

```
SELECT b1.*
FROM bio b1
JOIN
(
    SELECT Name, Min(ID) AS ID FROM bio
    GROUP BY Name
) b2
ON b1.Name = b2.Name AND b1.ID = b2.ID;
```

Comment: is there a way that i dont need to select each column ? so i just need to `*`. Because i have many column.

Comment: It is not possible with variables. You can use the `join` way to avoid that. I have updated my answer @Gagantous