# Ordering with Group by Mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

Additional help anyone.

I'm trying to get the value of per column 1 and 2 based on time which is column 4.

This is my table

[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve as a result.

[image]

as you can see the last row is not there anymore because row 1 and last row is the same when it comes to sensor_id and event_type but row 1 (time) is higher than last row(time)

This is my code so far

```
SELECT `sensor_id`,`event_type`,`value`, time FROM `events` ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get records with max value for each group of grouped SQL results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results)

Comment: You can check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results

Comment: What is the MySQL version you are using?  If it is MySQL 8.0, you can use window function to sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GROUP BY clause for this purpose:

```
SELECT `sensor_id`, `event_type`, `value`, max(`time`)
FROM `events`
GROUP BY `sensor_id`, `event_type`, `value`
ORDER BY max(`time`) DESC
```

Comment: It is correct however can we eliminate the last row since there is a similar sensor_id and event_type on that

Comment: @PFlorentino we can eliminate the last row, but before we do that, it's important to note that the last line does the sorting you applied in your original query. If there is no sorting, then the groups will not necessarily be ordered by time descendingly.