# Get non-aggregated column values without joins MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

I'm using mysql 8.0 and the table I have has a lot of rows so the solutions from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results) take too long to run.

Table example:

| ID | Name | Value | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 5 | alpha |
| 2 | b | 7 | beta |
| 3 | c | 8 | alpha |
| 4 | d | 10 | beta |

1. I would like to group it by category and then select the max value in each category
2. If the max values collide, I'd like to get the smallest ID (it will always be unique in my case)

Output table:

| ID | Name | Value | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | c | 8 | alpha |
| 4 | d | 10 | beta |

The ID and Category column are indexed and I need this query to be fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. I would like to group it by `category` and then select the `max value` in each category
> 2. If the max values collide, I'd like to get the `smallest ID` (it will always be unique in my case)

```sql
WITH cte AS ( 
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Value DESC, Id ASC) rn
    FROM src_table 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```