# Select latest row from group

Tags: mysql, sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

Could you help me with a query I'm trying to do please? The idea is to select the latest created_date from each val1, val2 unique combination.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fHc6MafduyibJdkLHe9cva/0

Expected result:

| val1 | val2 | num1 | num2 | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | A | 33 | 333 | 2022-11-03 |
| X | B | 66 | 666 | 2022-11-06 |
| X | C | 88 | 888 | 2022-11-08 |
| X | D | 99 | 999 | 2022-11-09 |
| Y | A | 111 | 1111 | 2022-11-11 |

**To the moderators**. My question is **different** from the one below because I'm using 2 tables instead of just one, and that's the complex part for me. Please see fiddle link for more details.
[Get records with max value for each group of grouped SQL results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the windowing function ROW_NUMBER() to avoid a self join:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT d.val1,
          d.val2,
          s.created_date,
          s.num1,
          s.num2,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.val1, d.val2
                            ORDER BY d.val1, d.val2, s.created_date DESC) AS row_num
   FROM scan AS s,
        dir AS d
   WHERE s.t2id=d.t2id) AS a
WHERE a.row_num=1;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mj9UExg3bqeHegyVsDcxFA/0

Comment: Upvoted, but FWIW the `ORDER BY d.val1, d.val2` is redundant, since you're partitioning by those columns. You only need `ORDER BY s.created_date DESC`.

Comment: Yeah, you right.... its an old habit... sorry for that ;)

Comment: just noticed that I have MySQL v5.6. and seems that the "OVER" is not allowed. Could you help me with a solution for this please? Thanks in advance