SQL query to get the maximum within a group, then attach another field to it
I have a derived table that looks like this



Salesperson
Quarter
Sales




Jack
Q1
100


Jack
Q2
10


Jack
Q3
110


Jack
Q4
100


Mary
Q1
80


Mary
Q2
200


Mary
Q3
25


Mary
Q4
30



I'd like to get the top sales person in each quarter, so  the result should look like



Quarter
Best Salesperon
Sales




Q1
Jack
100


Q2
Mary
200


Q3
Jack
110


Q4
Jack
200



The table is derived from a larger table that has many other fields, and the Sales column is the sum of individual sales for that salesperson in the original table, so I am actually using this in a WITH clause (e.g WITH t1 as (another complicated SQL) SELECT...
But if I try to use
 SELECT Quarter, Max(Sales), Salesperson from t1 group by Quarter 

The query fails with an error because Salesperson is not in the GROUP BY clause

Please don't add data as a screenshot since we would have to transcribe in order to replicate locally to solve. Instead use stackoverflow's table markdown or an ascii table inside a code block. Also, what version of mysql are you on? This feels like a job for ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QUARTER ORDER BY SALES DESC) as rn type of situation but those are only available in mysql 8+ versions.

Ok, I will try to reformat the table. I am using MySql 8.3

Bold transparent backcolor choice on your table images. In dark mode your tables are almost unreadable.

@BartMcEndree Almost?  I can't see a thing unless I clicked on the images :P

I fixed the tables, thanks for the tips on the formatting

There's actually a better "duplicate" for this than the one listed in the closing note - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results?rq=1

With MySQL 8.3 you can utilize window functions to do this logic:
SELECT Quarter, Sales, SalesPerson
FROM 
    (
         SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QUARTER ORDER BY SALES DESC) as rn
         FROM your_table_here
    ) dt
WHERE rn = 1;

That ROW_NUMBER() bit will partition the records into chunks/partitions for each distinct quarter. It will then order them by Sales and add a row number starting at 1. The WHERE clause then only selects the records with the rn of 1.

Thanks, I got this to work with a minor tweak of giving an alias to the derived table

Oh! I always forget the alias. I've added it into the answer.

Alternate approach: (using an older design pattern)
WITH t1 as (another complicated SQL) 

SELECT a.Quarter, Sales, a.Salesperson 
FROM t1 a
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(sales) Isales, Quarter 
            FROM T1
            GROUP BY Quarter ) b
  on A.quarter = b.quarter
 and a.sales = B.Isales

Newest Design pattern:

would be to use a lateral join something like.

.
WITH t1 as (another complicated SQL) 
SELECT a.Quarter, Sales, a.Salesperson 
FROM t1 a
INNER JOIN LATERAL (SELECT sales, Quarter 
            FROM T1
            ORDER BY Sales Desc
            LIMIT 1) b
  on A.quarter = b.quarter

